# How do I get the difference between two Dates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm creating an application which lets you define events with a time frame.  I want to automatically fill in the end date when the user selects or changes the start date.  I can't quite figure out, however, how to get the difference between the two times, and then how to create a new end Date using that difference.

Comment: related: [How to calculate number of days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542938/11107541)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In JavaScript, dates can be transformed to the number of milliseconds since the epoc by calling the `getTime()` method **or** just using the date in a numeric expression.

So to get the difference, just subtract the two dates.

To create a new date based on the difference, just pass the number of milliseconds in the constructor.

```
var oldBegin = ...
var oldEnd = ...
var newBegin = ...

var newEnd = new Date(newBegin + oldEnd - oldBegin);
```

This should just work

**EDIT**: Fixed bug pointed by @bdukes

**EDIT**:

For an explanation of the behavior, `oldBegin`, `oldEnd`, and `newBegin` are `Date` instances. Calling operators `+` and `-` will trigger Javascript auto casting and will automatically call the `valueOf()` prototype method of those objects. It happens that the `valueOf()` method is implemented in the `Date` object as a call to `getTime()`.

So basically: `date.getTime() === date.valueOf() === (0 + date) === (+date)`

Comment: What is the format required for .getTime() to work...
For example - new Date('22-12-2012 00:00').getTime() will not work...

Any ideas?

Comment: For date parsing in JS, I suggest you have a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-datetime-string-in-javascript

Comment: Are OldBegin, oldEnd, and NewBegin supposed to be `Date` objects? It's hard to tell what type of object they're supposed to be, since the variable declaration is omitted here.

Comment: Also, there's a function that you can use to add or subtract dates in JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1214753/975097

Comment: Be careful with adding numbers and days. See my answer below for explanation

Answer (score 27):

JavaScript perfectly supports date difference out of the box

https://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/v5twbe3h/

```
var msMinute = 60*1000, 
    msDay = 60*60*24*1000,
    a = new Date(2012, 2, 12, 23, 59, 59),
    b = new Date("2013 march 12");


console.log(Math.floor((b - a) / msDay) + ' full days between'); // 364
console.log(Math.floor(((b - a) % msDay) / msMinute) + ' full minutes between'); // 0
```

---

Now some pitfalls. Try this:

```
console.log(a - 10); // 1331614798990
console.log(a + 10); // mixed string
```

So if you have risk of adding a number and Date, convert Date to `number` directly.

```
console.log(a.getTime() - 10); // 1331614798990
console.log(a.getTime() + 10); // 1331614799010
```

My fist example demonstrates the power of Date object but it actually appears to be a time bomb

Comment: Dan, I found your example the easiest to understand and follow. Thanks.

Comment: The "pitfalls" are actually defaults based on the language specification. The subtraction operator `-` coerces the arguments to number, so the Date returns its time value. The `+` operator is overloaded, so might do addition, coercion to number or concatenation. Since Dates coerce to String in this case, `+` does concatenation. Confusion is not the fault of the Date object, but of overloading operators.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle and the results of the above lines of code in an edit. I also included a quick way to end up at NaN: b + 60000 - a

Comment: For those coming from search engines; avoid parsing strings by passing them to `new Date`, unless in specific formats (see [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51715259/215552)).

Answer (score 11):

***[See JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vvGPQ/1/)***

```
    var date1 = new Date();    
    var date2 = new Date("2025/07/30 21:59:00");
    //Customise date2 for your required future time

    showDiff();

function showDiff(date1, date2){

    var diff = (date2 - date1)/1000;
    diff = Math.abs(Math.floor(diff));

    var days = Math.floor(diff/(24*60*60));
    var leftSec = diff - days * 24*60*60;

    var hrs = Math.floor(leftSec/(60*60));
    var leftSec = leftSec - hrs * 60*60;

    var min = Math.floor(leftSec/(60));
    var leftSec = leftSec - min * 60;

    document.getElementById("showTime").innerHTML = "You have " + days + " days " + hrs + " hours " + min + " minutes and " + leftSec + " seconds before death.";

setTimeout(showDiff,1000);
}
```

for your HTML Code:

```
<div id="showTime"></div>
```

Comment: Not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed. Using the built–in parser to parse an unsupported string format is not a good way to create a Date.

Comment: For those coming from search engines; avoid parsing strings by passing them to `new Date`, unless in specific formats (see [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51715259/215552)).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about the time component, you can use `.getDate()` and `.setDate()` to just set the date part.

So to set your end date to 2 weeks after your start date, do something like this:

```
function GetEndDate(startDate)
{
    var endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()+14);
    return endDate;
}
```

To return the difference (in days) between two dates, do this:

```
function GetDateDiff(startDate, endDate)
{
    return endDate.getDate() - startDate.getDate();
}
```

Finally, let's modify the first function so it can take the value returned by 2nd as a parameter:

```
function GetEndDate(startDate, days)
{
    var endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + days);
    return endDate;
}
```

Comment: `GetDateDiff()` will break across month barriers. For example, 2011/04/26 and 2011/05/01 will return -25, but the offset should be 5 days.

Comment: var ds = new Date(2014, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0); var de = new Date(2014, 2, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0); GetDateDiff(ds,de) return 0

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @[Vincent Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript#41960), I ended up using your basic example, though it's actually `newBegin + oldEnd - oldBegin`.  Here's the simplified end solution:

```
    // don't update end date if there's already an end date but not an old start date
    if (!oldEnd || oldBegin) {
        var selectedDateSpan = 1800000; // 30 minutes
        if (oldEnd) {
            selectedDateSpan = oldEnd - oldBegin;
        }

       newEnd = new Date(newBegin.getTime() + selectedDateSpan));
    }
```

Comment: It's good point to explain why you are sometimes using `getTime` and sometimes not

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs, this function will calculate the difference between the 2 days, and return a result in days decimal.

```
// This one returns a signed decimal. The sign indicates past or future.

this.getDateDiff = function(date1, date2) {
    return (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}

// This one always returns a positive decimal. (Suggested by Koen below)

this.getDateDiff = function(date1, date2) {
    return Math.abs((date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

Comment: Place it in a `Math.abs()` call, and you will always get a positive decimal.

Comment: Nice suggestion Koen. That gives people 2 options: just the true date diff as you suggested, or a datediff with the sign indicating if the difference is in the past or future. :)

Comment: Please note that in JavaScript you can also add/substract a number in milliseconds to `date.getTime()` to get time in future/past.  `var nextMinute = new Date( someDate.getTime() + 60 * 1000 );

Comment: This is a typo? "between the 2 days". Probably between 2 dates.

Answer (score 2):

If using moment.js, there is a simpler solution, which will give you the difference in days in one single line of code.

```
moment(endDate).diff(moment(beginDate), 'days');
```

Additional details can be found in the [moment.js page](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Cheers,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

```
function compare()
{
  var end_actual_time    = $('#date3').val();

  start_actual_time = new Date();
  end_actual_time = new Date(end_actual_time);

  var diff = end_actual_time-start_actual_time;

  var diffSeconds = diff/1000;
  var HH = Math.floor(diffSeconds/3600);
  var MM = Math.floor(diffSeconds%3600)/60;

  var formatted = ((HH < 10)?("0" + HH):HH) + ":" + ((MM < 10)?("0" + MM):MM)
  getTime(diffSeconds);
}
function getTime(seconds) {
  var days = Math.floor(leftover / 86400);

  //how many seconds are left
  leftover = leftover - (days * 86400);

  //how many full hours fits in the amount of leftover seconds
  var hours = Math.floor(leftover / 3600);

  //how many seconds are left
  leftover = leftover - (hours * 3600);

  //how many minutes fits in the amount of leftover seconds
  var minutes = leftover / 60;

  //how many seconds are left
  //leftover = leftover - (minutes * 60);
  alert(days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative modificitaion extended code..

http://jsfiddle.net/vvGPQ/48/

```
showDiff();

function showDiff(){
var date1 = new Date("2013/01/18 06:59:00");   
var date2 = new Date();
//Customise date2 for your required future time

var diff = (date2 - date1)/1000;
var diff = Math.abs(Math.floor(diff));

var years = Math.floor(diff/(365*24*60*60));
var leftSec = diff - years * 365*24*60*60;

var month = Math.floor(leftSec/((365/12)*24*60*60));
var leftSec = leftSec - month * (365/12)*24*60*60;    

var days = Math.floor(leftSec/(24*60*60));
var leftSec = leftSec - days * 24*60*60;

var hrs = Math.floor(leftSec/(60*60));
var leftSec = leftSec - hrs * 60*60;

var min = Math.floor(leftSec/(60));
var leftSec = leftSec - min * 60;




document.getElementById("showTime").innerHTML = "You have " + years + " years "+ month + " month " + days + " days " + hrs + " hours " + min + " minutes and " + leftSec + " seconds the life time has passed.";

setTimeout(showDiff,1000);
}
```

Comment: Please add further clarification to your answer and use better English.

Comment: This solution is wrong because you use 365 days, neglecting leap years.

Comment: For those coming from search engines; avoid parsing strings by passing them to `new Date`, unless in specific formats (see [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51715259/215552)).

Answer (score 1):

**Below code  will return the days left from today to futures date.**

Dependencies: **jQuery and MomentJs.**

```
var getDaysLeft = function (date) {
  var today = new Date();
  var daysLeftInMilliSec = Math.abs(new Date(moment(today).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) - new Date(date));
  var daysLeft = daysLeftInMilliSec / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);   
  return daysLeft;
};

getDaysLeft('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Date objects and then use the `getTime()` function for both dates it will give you their respective times since Jan 1, 1970 in a number value. You can then get the difference between these numbers.

If that doesn't help you out, check out the complete documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Oh, yea, didn't notice, answers below this one are at most half a year old.

Answer (score 0):

this code fills the duration of study years when you input the start date and end date(qualify accured date) of study and check if the duration less than a year if yes the alert a message 
take in mind there are three input elements the first `txtFromQualifDate` and second `txtQualifDate` and third `txtStudyYears`

it will show result of number of years with fraction

```
function getStudyYears()
    {
        if(document.getElementById('txtFromQualifDate').value != '' && document.getElementById('txtQualifDate').value != '')
        {
            var d1 = document.getElementById('txtFromQualifDate').value;

            var d2 = document.getElementById('txtQualifDate').value;

            var one_day=1000*60*60*24;

            var x = d1.split("/");
            var y = d2.split("/");

            var date1=new Date(x[2],(x[1]-1),x[0]);

            var date2=new Date(y[2],(y[1]-1),y[0])

            var dDays = (date2.getTime()-date1.getTime())/one_day;

            if(dDays < 365)
            {
                alert("the date between start study and graduate must not be less than a year !");

                document.getElementById('txtQualifDate').value = "";
                document.getElementById('txtStudyYears').value = "";

                return ;
            }

            var dMonths = Math.ceil(dDays / 30);

            var dYears = Math.floor(dMonths /12) + "." + dMonths % 12;

            document.getElementById('txtStudyYears').value = dYears;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Never ever parse date strings to find year because string appearence (esp. separators) differs among browsers. Use `getFullYear` which was designed for that. ------- See datejs library on googlecode which possibly supports most corner cases

Comment: thanks for advice @Dan but it worked and tested for me on real goverment project (different browsers) is it that weak programming practive ? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function dayDiff()
{
     var start = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
     var end= document.getElementById("date_picker").value;
     var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; 
     var firstDate = new Date(start);
     var secondDate = new Date(end);    
     var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
    document.getElementById("leave").value =diffDays ;
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="datepicker"value=""/>
<input type="text" name="date_picker" onclick="function dayDiff()" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="leave" value=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getDaysLeft = function (date1, date2) {
   var daysDiffInMilliSec = Math.abs(new Date(date1) - new Date(date2));
   var daysLeft = daysDiffInMilliSec / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);   
   return daysLeft;
};
var date1='2018-05-18';
var date2='2018-05-25';
var dateDiff = getDaysLeft(date1, date2);
console.log(dateDiff);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the date difference in milliseconds between two dates:

```js
var diff = Math.abs(date1 - date2);
```

I'm not sure what you mean by converting the difference back into a date though.

Answer (score 0):

Many answers here are based on a direct subtraction of Date objects like `new Date(…) - new Date(…)`. This is **syntactically wrong**. Browsers still accept it because of backward compatibility. But modern JS linters will throw at you.

The right way to calculate date differences in milliseconds is `new Date(…).getTime() - new Date(…).getTime()`:

```
// Time difference between two dates
let diffInMillis = new Date(…).getTime() - new Date(…).getTime()
```

If you want to calculate the time difference to now, you can just remove the argument from the first `Date`:

```
// Time difference between now and some date
let diffInMillis = new Date().getTime() - new Date(…).getTime()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function checkdate() {
    var indate = new Date()
    indate.setDate(dat)
    indate.setMonth(mon - 1)
    indate.setFullYear(year)

    var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    var diff = Math.ceil((indate.getTime() - now.getTime()) / (one_day))
    var str = diff + " days are remaining.."
    document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = str.fontcolor('blue')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

THIS IS WHAT I DID ON MY SYSTEM.

```
var startTime=("08:00:00").split(":");
var endTime=("16:00:00").split(":");
var HoursInMinutes=((parseInt(endTime[0])*60)+parseInt(endTime[1]))-((parseInt(startTime[0])*60)+parseInt(startTime[1]));
console.log(HoursInMinutes/60);
```