# jQuery UI, Calendar, find out if date given is over 2 years old

Tags: jquery, date, calendar

Hay Guys, I'm using the bog standard Calendar from the jQuery UI system. The result shown (after a user clicks a date) is MM/DD/YYYY.

I want to check that this date is not old than 2 years old

ie

say a user picks

```
01/27/2004
```

this should say that the date is older than 2 years. However,

```
12/25/2008
```

should pass the test.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var selectedDate = new Date('01/27/2004');
selectedDate.setFullYear(selectedDate.getFullYear()+2);

var moreThan2YearsOld = selectedDate < new Date();
```

Answer (score 2):

`DateDiff` returns the difference between dates in milliseconds:

```
function DateDiff(date1, date2){
    return Math.abs(date1.getTime()-date2.getTime());
}
```

... and if this is bigger than the number of microseconds equivalent to two years ...

```
date1 = new Date("01/27/2004");
date2 = new Date(); // now

DateDiff(date1, date2);
// => 185717385653
//    31536000000 // == two years
```

The number of milliseconds per years is 31536000000.

More on that matter: [What's the best way to calculate date difference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327429/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [getFullYear](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getFullYear.asp) function to check this.

You could use something like (untested):

```
var date = new Date($('#calendarId').val());
var today = new Date();
var moreThan2Years = (today.getFullYear() - date.getFullYear()) > 2;
```