# How to create a jQuery timer that starts on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer, jquery-events

I am using jQuery 1.4. I want create the timer which starts on `keyup` event and resets on key press event. I want to use `$.ajax` request to send the time interval to the server. All I could find was countdown timers.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail, please?  I don't quite understand how `$.ajax` and timers fit together.

Comment: I am currently working on a single field form. The form submits on keyup using jquery's $.ajax method. I also want to save the time interval between the key up and key press event. I was wondering if I could use jquery to find the time interval using jqeury.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this very simply by comparing timestamps using native Javascript functions -- no jQuery necessary for the timing logic:

```
var start, end, interval;

$('form' /*or whatever selector*/).keydown(function() {
    start = new Date();
}).keyup(function() {
    end = new Date();

    interval = end.getTime() - start.getTime(); // interval in milliseconds

    // do your AJAX here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [`Date`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) object. Instantiate one on key down, and then another on key up and compare the two to find the time interval. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327429/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript) has more detail.