# Javascript month difference

Tags: javascript, date

How do I calculate difference in months in Javascript?

Please note there are similar questions such as:
[What's the best way to calculate date difference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327429/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

But these are based around MS difference, when some months have different number of days than others!

Any easy way to calculate month difference between 2 dates?

Just to be clear, I need to know how many months the dates span, for example:

```
Jan 29th 2010, and Feb 1st 2010 = 2 months
Jan 1st 2010, and Jan 2nd 2010 = 1 month
Feb 14th 2010, Feb 1st 2011 = 13 months
Feb 1st 2010, March 30th 2011 = 14 months
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by month difference? Whole calendar months eg 12Apr2010 -> 16Jun2010 = 1 ; or month lengths taken from the start date eg 12Apr2010 -> 16Jun2010 = 2. Or are you wanting to calculate decimal part also? In which case. What value does each day get? Does a month in Feb get 1/28 whereas a month in december gets 1/31? Then there's leap years...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: Sorry, to be clear it's the total # months the date ranges span.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
DisplayTo.getMonth() - DisplayFrom.getMonth() + (12 * (DisplayTo.getFullYear() - DisplayFrom.getFullYear())));
```

getMonth minus getMonth gives you the month difference between the dates two months.

We then multiply 12 by the number of years difference and add this to the result giving us the full month span.

Comment: Nice one liner.. test case available here if anyone interested. http://jsfiddle.net/E5Bz3/1/ :)

Comment: Does not work if, for example, StartDate = Dec 12, 2012 and EndDate = Jan 1, 2013. The result will be 1, not 2.

Answer (score 5):

[**edit**] Based on comment, I stand corrected. Using the accepted answer I'd use somethng like:

```
var  datefrom = new Date('2001/03/15')
    ,dateto = new Date('2011/07/21')
    ,nocando = datefrom<dateto ? null : 'datefrom > dateto!'
    ,diffM = nocando || 
             dateto.getMonth() - datefrom.getMonth() 
              + (12 * (dateto.getFullYear() - datefrom.getFullYear()))
    ,diffY = nocando || Math.floor(diffM/12)
    ,diffD = dateto.getDate()-datefrom.getDate()
    ,diffYM = nocando || 
               (diffY>0 ? ' Year(s) ' : '')
               + diffM%12+' Month(s) '+(diffD>0? (diffD+' day(s)') : '') ;

 console.log(diffYM); //=> 10 Year(s) 4 Month(s) 6 day(s)
```

Comment: this is wrong if the 2 dates is : date1 = new Date('2011/1/04')
    ,date2 = new Date('2010/12/04') it will give wrong answer

Comment: You're absolutely right, better use Gullens oneliner. Edited answer based on that.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following on the website http://ditio.net/2010/05/02/javascript-date-difference-calculation/:

```
inMonths: function(d1, d2) {
        var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
        var d2Y = d2.getFullYear();
        var d1M = d1.getMonth();
        var d2M = d2.getMonth();

        return (d2M+12*d2Y)-(d1M+12*d1Y);
    }
```

In your case, since you want to include all months in the date span, I would just modify the above code by adding 1 to it: `return (d2M+12*d2Y)-(d1M+12*d1Y) + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

```
function calcualteMonthYr(){
    var fromDate =new Date($('#txtDurationFrom2').val()); // Date picker (text fields)
    var toDate = new Date($('#txtDurationTo2').val());
    var months=0;
        months = (toDate.getFullYear() - fromDate.getFullYear()) * 12;
        months -= fromDate.getMonth();
        months += toDate.getMonth();
            if (toDate.getDate() < fromDate.getDate()){
                months--;
            }
    $('#txtTimePeriod2').val(months); // result
}
```

Comment: Maybe elaborate on your answer a bit