# Need ASP or Javascript Function to get Hours

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript

I need a function to get hours from two variable (date+time)

```
var a date +time

var b date +time

result = a-b in hours
```

Comment: What type of data do the two variables hold - are they date objects, strings, or something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327429/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ASP VBScript, the [`DateDiff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhtyw595%28VS.85%29.aspx) function will do business

`result = DateDiff('h', a, b)`

Comment: This is fine , but how can I call it on client side ? 
eg. <input type="text" onFocus"Result" value"">

Comment: you can't - ASP is server-side. All you can do is output the result directly, eg `<input type="text" value="<% =DateDiff("h", CDate("01/01/11"), Now()) %>">` or as the return value from an AJAX call. If you want 100% client-side you'd use the javascript method

Comment: Hi,
I have working on this code

"dim m1 , m2 , m3 
m1 = request.Form("outdate")&" "& request.Form("outtime")
m2 = request.Form("indate") &" " & request.Form("intime")

m3 = DateDiff("h",m1,m2)

but this gives errors datatype mismatch

Comment: @Dev without knowing what's really in the `Form` collection, I can't tell you but you could try explicitly converting `m1` and `m2` to dates before the `DateDiff` with `CDate()`

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, use the UTC() function.  It will return the milliseconds since 1/1/1970.  Get the difference between the to values and convert to hours.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object internally stores dates as integers, counting the number of milliseconds since 0:00 on January 1st, 1970.

Thus, adding/subtracting two JS dates from each others will result in the difference between the two, in millisconds.  Converting those to hours is easy when you know there’s 60 * 60 * 1000 = 3 600 000 ms in one hour:

```
var a = new Date(old),
    b = new Date(newer),
    hoursBetween = (b - a) / 3600000;
```

Comment: function dif() {
  var fromDate = document.form1.outdate.value + document.form1.outtime.value ;
  var toDate  = document.form1.indate.value + document.form1.intime.value ;

var a = new Date(fromDate),
  b = new Date(toDate),
  hoursBetween = (a - b) / 3600000;

  
alert(hoursBetween);