# Problem with comparing dates in javascript

Tags: javascript

HI,

I have the following code that is supposed to compare two dates:

```
 var d = ($('#day').val());
 var m = ($('#month').val() -1);
 var y = $('#year').val(); 
 var birthdate = new Date(y,m,d);
 alert('birthdate is' + birthdate);
 var today = new Date();
 alert('today is'+ today); 
 var diff = (today - birthdate);
 years = Math.floor(diff/(1000*60*60*24*365));
 alert(years);
```

It's basically working but I'm interested to see if the date of birth makes the user over 18 or not. So I've tried to put in 30th march 1993 - which would make the user 17. I'm alerting out the birthdate and it gives me back the correct date (mon mar 29 1993 00:00:00 GMT + 0100 BST)....however this is evaluating to 18 (alert(years) in the above code) when it should evaluate to seventeen. It's not until I put in 3rd April 1993 that it evaluates to 17.

Any ideas?

Comment: Leap years are mucking things up

Comment: See the [great source of all knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year) for more information about calendar years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you forgot the leap years.

These years had 366 days and occur usually every four years, so in any 18 years there are about four days more than 365*18, thus moving the neccessary start date four days ahead.

Probably in this case it is easier to check

```
if ((nowyear - birthyear > 18) 
   || ((nowyear - birthyear == 18)&&(nowmonth - birthmonth > 0))
   || ((nowyear - birthyear == 18)&&(nowmonth == birthmonth)&&(nowday - birthday >= 0)))
  // you're 18!
```

Comment: Your last condition only checks that the months are equal and the current day is greater than the birthday, but doesn't check the years.

Comment: I don't know how to split the date up in to years and months. I have the birth year/month/day split up but how do i create todays date and get that in months/days/years?

Answer (score 2):

You have to mind leap-years, timezones... before reinventing the wheel, I recommend that you use [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/).

```
if((18).years().ago().isBefore(birthdate)) {
  // handle underage visitors
}
```

Comment: For sure. Time and dates are messy and inconsistent. Hand rolled solutions involving them almost always include bugs. Much better to go with a well tested library if possible.

Comment: THis doesn't work. I just get and error saying (18).years().ago().isBefore is not a function...I do have the library included

Comment: This library is in alpha testing. I've just done some simple calculations with it and it is not reliable

Comment: My fault. `isBefore` was introduced after that alpha release. If using `datejs` it's best to use the latest version from [https://github.com/datejs/Datejs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for age, why not just go the simple route and deal with years, months, and days?

```
function findAge( birthday ){
   var today = new Date();
   var age = today.getFullYears() - birthday.getFullYears();
   if( today.getMonth() - birthday.getMonth() < 0 ){
      age--;
   }
   else if( today.getDay() - birthday.getDay() < 0 && today.getMonth() == birthday.getMonth() ){
      age--;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327429/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

Comment: That doesn't answer the OP's question.