# Get difference between two dates using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Can any one suggest a jQuery plugin for calculating the difference between two dates (dates may contain time also) and show it as '32 days', '13 hours', '20 min' etc?

Comment: Why jQuery hen this can be done with native JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to calculate date difference in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327429/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

Comment: and duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend using the excellent [datejs framework](http://www.datejs.com/) to easily do all your date time calculations

Comment: date.js never got past Alpha-1 and is outdated since 2007. I would very much discourage using it!

Answer (score 12):

You can add, subtract and do many other things with the *native* JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.  It's [powerful enough](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for most of your needs. If using it, you save kilobytes of page size and make the code understandable for everyone (probably 90% of JavaScript developers have never used any plugins to calculate dates)

The thing I hate about Date object is it does not have a [built-in formatted output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript).

For example, you cannot tell the localized day of the week or month name without string parsing. Then [datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) comes to help you.

### What can a Date object do?

```
var msMinute = 60*1000, 
    msDay = 60*60*24*1000,
    a = new Date(2012, 2, 12, /* days, hours*/ 23, 59, 59),
    b = new Date("2013 march 12"), /* string */
    c = new Date(),                /* now */
    d = new Date(c.getTime() + msDay - msMinute);       /* tomorrow - minute */


console.log(a.getUTCHours());
console.log(typeof (b - a + 1000));
console.log(Math.floor((b - a) / msDay) + ' full days between');
console.log(Math.floor(((b - a) % msDay) / msMinute) + ' full minutes between');
console.log('Today is ' + c.getDay() + ' day of week');
console.log('Tomorrow is ' + d.getDay() + ' day of week');
console.log('Your timezone offset is ' + c.getTimezoneOffset() + ' minutes');
```

[Easily calculate days till Christmas](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml)

And, sometimes there is more truth in a joke then you could ever expect
[image: OMG, a scary dream]

Comment: If adding a number to date always use `getTime()`. This code does not work `console.log(a + 10)` and this works    `console.log(a.getTime() + 10)`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a pretty simple Javascript implementation I just hacked up.  You can do the math to extend this to months or years or remove the plurals for 1 values if needed.

```
var dateDiff = function ( d1, d2 ) {
    var diff = Math.abs(d1 - d2);
    if (Math.floor(diff/86400000)) {
        return Math.floor(diff/86400000) + " days";
    } else if (Math.floor(diff/3600000)) {
        return Math.floor(diff/3600000) + " hours";
    } else if (Math.floor(diff/60000)) {
        return Math.floor(diff/60000) + " minutes";
    } else {
        return "< 1 minute";
    }
};

dateDiff(new Date(1990, 1, 1), new Date(1990, 1, 13)) // -> 12 days
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [jQuery EasyDate](https://web.archive.org/web/20131010010951/http://easydate.parshap.com/) is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, confirming that this worked for me and indeed will achieve what was asked in question. Plenty of examples provided.

Comment: Broken Link in 2018

Comment: Thanks, I updated with an Archive.org snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

```
day1= $("#tMTLCLsDay").val();
month1= $("#tMTLCLsMnth").val();
year1= $("#tMTLCLsYr").val();
hour1= $("#tMTLCLs_HOUR").val();
min1= $("#tMTLCLs_MIN").val();
var Date1=month1+ "/" + day1+ "/" + year1+ " " + hour1 + ":" + min1+ ": 00" ;

day2= $("#tMTLCLsDay").val();
month2= $("#tMTLCLsMnth").val();
year2= $("#tMTLCLsYr").val();
hour3= $("#tMTLCLs_HOUR").val();
hour2= $("#tMTLCLs_MIN").val();
var Date2=month2+ "/" + day2+ "/" + year2+ " " + hour2 + ":" + hour2 + ": 00" ;


if(Date.parse(Date1)<Date.parse(Date2))
{
alert("Date 2 is large");
}
```