# Determine minutes until midnight

Tags: javascript

How would you go about determining how many minutes until midnight of the current day using javascript?

Comment: Maybe this post can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847165/jquery-get-difference-between-two-dates

Comment: Midnight according to the client's computer, or according to the server that sent the client the js?

Comment: @JesseB: server time, it's for console script

Comment: @Parson: All the answers below refer to client's midnight. You should calculate server time on the server

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
function minutesUntilMidnight() {
    var midnight = new Date();
    midnight.setHours( 24 );
    midnight.setMinutes( 0 );
    midnight.setSeconds( 0 );
    midnight.setMilliseconds( 0 );
    return ( midnight.getTime() - new Date().getTime() ) / 1000 / 60;
}
```

Comment: I recommend kennebeck's or RobG's answer. Just not to repeat myself, I'm giving the link with problem explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15792909/139361

Comment: consider using `midnight.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps:

```js
function minsToMidnight() {
  var now = new Date();
  var then = new Date(now);
  then.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
  return (then - now) / 6e4;
}

console.log(minsToMidnight());
```

or

```js
function minsToMidnight() {
  var msd = 8.64e7;
  var now = new Date();
  return (msd - (now - now.getTimezoneOffset() * 6e4) % msd) / 6e4;
}

console.log(minsToMidnight())
```

and there is:

```js
function minsToMidnight(){
  var d = new Date();
  return (-d + d.setHours(24,0,0,0))/6e4;
}

console.log(minsToMidnight());
```

or even a one-liner:

```js
minsToMidnight = () => (-(d = new Date()) + d.setHours(24,0,0,0))/6e4;

console.log(minsToMidnight());
```

Comment: Why are they all slightly different?

Comment: @quick007—because of the time that elapses between clicking the buttons. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can get the current timestamp, set the hours to 24,

and subtract the old timestamp from the new one.

```
function beforeMidnight(){
    var mid= new Date(), 
    ts= mid.getTime();
    mid.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
    return Math.floor((mid - ts)/60000);
}
```

**alert(beforeMidnight()+ ' minutes until midnight')**

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner to get milliseconds until midnight

```
new Date().setHours(24,0,0,0) - Date.now()
```

And for the minutes until midnight, we divide that by 60 and then by 1000

```
(new Date().setHours(24,0,0,0) - Date.now()) / 60 / 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an alternative solution which works for any hour of the day.

```
const timeUntilHour = (hour) => {
    if (hour < 0 || hour > 24) throw new Error("Invalid hour format!");

    const now = new Date();
    const target = new Date(now);

    if (now.getHours() >= hour)
        target.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);

    target.setHours(hour);
    target.setMinutes(0);
    target.setSeconds(0);
    target.setMilliseconds(0);

    return target.getTime() - now.getTime();
}

const millisecondsUntilMidnight = timeUntilHour(24);
const minutesUntilMidnight = millisecondsUntilMidnight / (60 * 1000);
```