# How to calculate ms since midnight in Javascript

Tags: javascript, time

What is the best way to calculate the time passed since (last) midnight in ms?

Comment: [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) Get a date object for (last) midnight and subtract "now" from it... - Just simple math

Comment: @Andreas Midnight subtracted from now gives a negative time ;)

Comment: Thanks guys! Kolnik, you solution also gives a negative time?

Comment: @Kolink Olga asks for the milliseconds between midnight and now. There is no preference for the sign :P But you're right :)

Comment: @Olga Wow, I'm stupid sometimes. That's what I get for being up a 3AM!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Create a new date using the current day/month/year, and get the difference.

```
var now = new Date(),
    then = new Date(
        now.getFullYear(),
        now.getMonth(),
        now.getDate(),
        0,0,0),
    diff = now.getTime() - then.getTime(); // difference in milliseconds
```

Comment: You can do that a lot easier by copying the date object and setting the time to 00:00:00. Your answer may be wrong if the clock ticks between creating the two dates.

Comment: It works wrong in `2 / 365 * 100%` cases because of daylight saving change

Comment: @Dan: nope, the Date object uses timestamps which are indifferent to DST. Add on the fact that DST changes at some early time in the morning but not midnight, it's fine

Comment: Well, I and RobG are wrong in the comments above. @RobG (about his second sentence): the system date is got only once here, and the second date is calculated with `now` as a basis, so the clock can't actually 'tick' here

Comment: Edited to take the downwote away

Answer (score 39):

A bunch of answers so here another:

```
var d = new Date(), e = new Date(d);
var msSinceMidnight = e - d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

As a function:

```
function getMsSinceMidnight(d) {
  var e = new Date(d);
  return d - e.setHours(0,0,0,0);
}

alert(getMsSinceMidnight(new Date()));
```

Comment: This one is good. It correctly handles daylight savings time.

Answer (score 13):

Many answers except [RobG's (recommended answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10946213/139361), [Kolink's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944417/139361) and [Lai's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944444/139361) are wrong here

Let's look closer together

---

*First mistake*

[OptimusCrime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944456/139361) and [Andrew D.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944701/139361) answers:

As [Mala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146587/mala) sugested, if the daylight saving correction was applied the nearest midnight, we get incorrect value. Let's debug:

1. Suppose it's last Sunday of March
2. The time is fixed at 2 am.
3. If we see 10 am on the clock, there's actually 11 hours passed from midnight
4. But instead we count `10 * 60 * 60 * 1000` ms
5. The trick is played when midnight happens in different DST state then current

---

*Second mistake*

[kennebeck's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10947970/139361) answer:

As [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) wrote, the clock can tick if you get the system time twice. We can even appear in different dates sometimes. You can reproduce this in a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; true; i++) {
    if ((new Date()).getTime() - (new Date()).getTime()) {
        alert(i); // console.log(i);  // for me it's about a 1000
        break;
    }
}
```

---

*Third* is my personal pitfall you could possibly experience

Consider the following code:

```
var d = new Date(),
    msSinceMidnight = d - d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

`msSinceMidnight` is always `0` as the object is changed during computation before the substraction operation

---

At last, this code works:

```
var d = new Date(),
    msSinceMidnight = d.getTime() - d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 6):

Simpler to write, if you don't mind creating two dates.

```
var msSinceMidnight= new Date()-new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var d=new Date();
// offset from midnight in Greenwich timezone
var msFromMidnightInGMT=d%86400000;
// offset from midnight in locale timezone
var msFromMidnightLocale=(d.getTime()-d.getTimezoneOffset()*60000)%86400000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = new Date();
var d = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0); 

var difference = today.getTime() - d.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seconds since midnight would simply be to display the time, but instead of using hours:minutes:seconds, everything is converted into seconds.

I think this should do it:

```
var now = new Date();    
var hours = now.getHours()*(60*60);
var minutes = now.getMinutes()*60;
var seconds = now.getSeconds();

var secSinceMidnight = hours+minutes+seconds;
```

Comment: @Mala do you mean this code fails if the daylight savings correction was applied the latest midnight? Then Andrew D.'s answer fails as well

Comment: @Dan: this answer assumes that 8am means 8 hours since midnight, which is not true on days when daylight savings begins or ends. I haven't looked closely at Andrew's answer, but in any case I recommed RobG's answer above, because I can confirm that it works, and is not affected by a potential clock tick between the two Date declarations

Comment: I guess it really depends on what you are looking for. In my case I get a reading from a server with a time which I need to compare to the actual clock to check if the reading is not too late. In effect this is the only method which ensure correctness as it "clean up" any consideration about DST. In other cases might not be the right solution. +1