# How do I convert human readable hours into milliseconds using javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

Given "3:00 AM" or "7:00 PM", are there **built in functions** (like Date) for me to convert these into milliseconds? 3:00 AM would be 3 hours in milliseconds, while 7:00 PM would be 19 hours in milliseconds.

Comment: I could be wrong but is this not covered in:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944396/how-to-calculate-ms-since-midnight-in-javascript

Comment: @BrianLangbecker, Not exactly the same because the current question involves parsing the time string. Also it tries to calculate the milliseconds elapsed for a specific time, not the current time elapsed since midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is any built-in function for this, however it would not be complicated to achieve what you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

First, create a date with 0 elapsed milliseconds:

```
var d = new Date(0);
```

Parse your time string and set the hours of the date accordingly:

```
var t = timeString.match(/(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}) ([AP]M)/),
    h = parseInt(t[1], 10),
    isAm = t[3] === 'AM',
    isMidnight = h === 12 && isAm,
    isNoon = h === 12 && !isAm;

d.setUTCHours(isMidnight? 0 : h + (isAm || isNoon? 0 : 12), parseInt(t[2], 10));
```

Use the `getTime` function to get the milliseconds:

```
console.log(d.getTime()); //10800000
```

Here's a re-usable function:

```
function getTimeMilliseconds(timeString) {
    var t = timeString.match(/(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}) ([AP]M)/),
        h = parseInt(t[1], 10),
        isAm = t[3] === 'AM',
        isMidnight = h === 12 && isAm,
        isNoon = h === 12 && !isAm;

    return new Date(0).setUTCHours(isMidnight? 0 : h + (isAm || isNoon? 0 : 12), parseInt(t[2], 10));
}

getTimeMilliseconds('3:00 AM');
```

*Note that you don't really need the `Date` object to achieve this, but I use it because it does the math for you, however you could always do `hours * 3600000 + minutes * 60000`.*

```
function getTimeMilliseconds(timeString) {
    var t = timeString.match(/(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}) ([AP]M)/),
        h = parseInt(t[1], 10),
        isAm = t[3] === 'AM',
        isMidnight = h === 12 && isAm,
        isNoon = h === 12 && !isAm;

    return (isMidnight? 0 : h + (isAm || isNoon? 0 : 12)) * 3600000 + parseInt(t[2], 10) * 60000;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `12:00 PM` (which should be 12 hours, but will be counted as 24.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @plalx . I guess functions like these are not built in because AM and PM is an english thing.