# Minutes since midnight in Momentjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, momentjs

In pure JS, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10946213/194982) would be how.

How can I find out the number of minutes since midnight for a given `moment` object (without extracting to `Date`)?

- Must take into account DSTs
- Minutes should be rounded
- Must work with local time (not convert to UTC)

Comment: Is this a homework? The restricts to resolve the issue plus the fact that I do not see any code being shared make this question really odd.

Comment: @Dalorzo no, see my [own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25130168/194982) that I have just added. Just unsure if I have taken into account various edge cases in my attempt.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
// Your moment
var mmt = moment();

// Your moment at midnight
var mmtMidnight = mmt.clone().startOf('day');

// Difference in minutes
var diffMinutes = mmt.diff(mmtMidnight, 'minutes');
```

By default, moment#diff will return number rounded down. If you want the floating point number, pass true as the third argument. Before 2.0.0, moment#diff returned rounded number, not a rounded down number.

Consider this pseudocode because I haven't test to see if the difference takes into account DST.

Comment: This was close but the problem is `startOf` doesn't return midnight but mutates the object. I just created a new object, mutated it and then compared the two.

Comment: You're right.  Immutable objects is coming to moment soon (I hope).  In the meantime, do mmt.clone().startOf().

Comment: Is the second clone() (on the last line) necessary?

Comment: No, I guess not.  I just tested and diff does not change mmt's original value.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: This have an Issue with day time saving...
The exact day of DST change, will give you the wrong time (which is the right calculation, but maybe not what you are searching for)

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have at the moment:

```
    if (!moment.isMoment(mmt)) {
        return 0;
    }
    var hh = mmt.get('hour');
    var mm = mmt.get('minute');
    return hh*60 + mm;
```

I am not sure if it takes into account various edge cases; comment if this is the case, or provide an alternate answer.

Comment: It wont' work on the days that DST starts and ends, but in some cases you explicitly don't want those (for instance if comparing to opening times)