# Using moment.js timezone to get day extremes in another timezone (but the answer in UTC)

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I want to work out the day extremes (midnight to midnight) for a particular day, where that day is a whole number of days relative to now (i.e. relative to `Date.now()`)... but for a different timezone to UTC.  But I want the answer (midnight times) back in UTC time (in milliseconds, similar to what you get with `Date.now()`), so that I can feed those to an API that expects UTC times, to get the exact right time range of data.  I have tried to use [moment.js timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) but am getting horribly stuck... I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31758270/4070848) but it doesn't work in a different timezone.

Comment: Can you share one example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment will allow you to do this fairly easily:

```
function getUTCMidnightMillis(timezone, days_ago) {
  return moment()               // Current time.
    .tz(timezone)               // Convert to desired timezone.
    .subtract(days_ago, 'days') // Go back x days.
    .startOf('day')             // Get start of day, aka Midnight!
    .utc()                      // Convert value into UTC.
    .valueOf()                  // Return milliseconds since unix epoch.
}

console.log("Midnight in Denver:", getUTCMidnightMillis("America/Denver", 0))
console.log("Midnight in New York:", getUTCMidnightMillis("America/New_York", 0))
```

Which produces the output:

```
Midnight in Denver: 1594274400000
Midnight in New York: 1594267200000
```

And indeed, you can verify that is correct:

```
new Date(1594274400000).toISOString()
// Produces: "2020-07-09T06:00:00.000Z"
```

For the 9th of July, 2020, we observe daylight savings in Denver, making our UTC offset -6 hours. So the above timestamp (6:00am UTC) is the same moment at which it is midnight in Denver.

Comment: Note that the `.utc()` part seems to make no difference?

Comment: @drmrbrewer—yes, `.utc()` doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you consider using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), which is essentially the replacement for moment.js.

The algorithm is create a date for now in the required representative location, subtract the required number of days, then set to the start of day, then get the time value, e.g.

```js
let DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

// Create date for 00:00:00 3 days ago in Denver
let d = DateTime.local()                   // Create a date
                .setZone('America/Denver') // Set to Denver
                .minus({days:3})           // Subtract 3 days
                .startOf('day');           // Set to start of day
// Create date for end of day
let e = d.endOf('day');

// Denver 3 days ago at start and end of day
console.log('Start of day: ' + d.toISO() + '\nTime value  : ' + d.ts);
console.log('End   of day: ' + e.toISO() + '\ntime value  : ' + e.ts);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.24.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Note that 3 days ago in Denver might be a different date to 3 days ago in the host system because of the offset differences. E.g in Sydney, Australia at 9 am on 20 July it's 5 pm on 19 July in Denver, so subtracting 3 days in Sydney is 17 July but 16 July in Denver.

Comment: Thanks for bringing Luxon to my attention.  Seems pretty similar to moment though?  Where is it stated that Luxon "is essentially the replacement for moment.js"?

Comment: Having played with luxon for a bit, I'm finding it a lot more intuitive than moment.  In particular, I'm a big fan of the `keepLocalTime` option when moving between time zones (https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/zones.html#keeplocaltime).  I couldn't find any equivalent in moment, and it's exactly what I need for another issue I'm trying to get my head around.