# Run code once a day

Tags: javascript, loops

I was just wondering if it is possible to have a javascript for loop that only iterates through the loop once a day i.e. when the date changes?

```
for(i=0; i < myArray.length; i++){

    alert(myArray[i]);

}
```

So in the above loop, let it run, and freeze it or something only till the data changes, and the do another iteration, and just keep on doing that.. You know what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will your code be running in node.js or other server-side environment or in a browser?

Comment: Then `setInterval` is a good choice.

Comment: @RayToal - how can it be a good choice? it will run multiple times every refresh and not once a day.

Comment: Good point - a day is indeed a gigantic interval for a browser, or any client-side agent.

Comment: @Tiwaz89 - please reconsider the vote since the chosen answer isn't so good

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) is the best way to go when you don't have a server (because a user can change the computer's time and break your logic, and using a server it's harder to hack this)

### Method below is more bulletproof:

```
// checks if one day has passed. 
function hasOneDayPassed()
  // get today's date. eg: "7/37/2007"
  var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

  // if there's a date in localstorage and it's equal to the above: 
  // inferring a day has yet to pass since both dates are equal.
  if( localStorage.yourapp_date == date ) 
      return false;

  // this portion of logic occurs when a day has passed
  localStorage.yourapp_date = date;
  return true;
}


// some function which should run once a day
function runOncePerDay(){
  if( !hasOneDayPassed() ) return false;

  // your code below
  alert('Good morning!');
}


runOncePerDay(); // run the code
runOncePerDay(); // does not run the code
```

Comment: at the bottom you have written `runOncePerDay(); //run the code` `runOncePerDay(); //does not run the code` but they are identical? What am I missing?

Comment: @jmfbot - it's just a demonstration that shows the function can only run once a day, so the second call won't *alert* anything since on the second call `hasOneDayPassed()` will return true (until 1 day passses)

Answer (score 4):

If you want something to happen at predefined intervals, you can set a timeout/interval:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

For example:

```
var dayInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
setInterval(function() { alert("foo"); },dayInMilliseconds );
```

edit: since you mentioned that the code will be running in a browser, this assumes the browser is running for at least 24 hrs and will not work otherwise.

Comment: This is basically right, although I think the OP wants it to run local-time midnight.  If that's the case, you should instead compute `millisecondsToMidnight`.

Comment: @nolegs That's really good, thanks nolegs. But as apsillers says, I wouldn't like it to run every 24hours from time of execution. But itterate every night at midnight.

Comment: You can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583694/determine-minutes-until-midnight 
This will give you milliseconds until midnight, but the browser will obviously still have to be running at midnight for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

the best way to achieve it is by creating a cookie that lasts for1 day..
Even if after the refresh of the web page or browser gets closed that countdown will still continue..

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 86400, "/");
```

This means 86400 = 1 day

Hope it helps