# How to update current day at midnight or basically on new day in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have web watch what should work 24/7. It displaying digital time and current day. Nothing else.

My problem is that when time past midnight, current day won't update and I need to restart whole application.

I tried to add setTimeout for showDate() function, but it didn't help me. I was thinking about moving +1 on array of days. Is there anything more effective?

```
function showdate(){

    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay();

    var name = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][day];

    document.getElementById("date").textContent = name;

}

showdate();

function showTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
    var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
    var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
    var session = "AM";

    if(h === 0){
        h = 24;
    }

    /*if(h > 12){
        h = h - 12;
        session = "PM";
    }*/

    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

    var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    /*var sess = session;*/
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").textContent = time;
   /* document.getElementById("PM").textContent = sess;*/

    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);     

   }

showTime();
```

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Why don't you just re-run `showdate` periodically?

Comment: @VLAZ Shouldn't it make setInterval / setTimetout? What do you mean by re-run?

Comment: @Cabry You would use setInterval rather than setTimeout, with an interval of 1000ms

Comment: How you are showing current time? is time update function in setInterval?

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra I edited my questioin

Comment: You need to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32428268/5146848

Comment: why not update day inside your showTime function or you can use setInterval(()=>{showTime(); showDate();}) instead of recursion

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't execute itself automatically. You shall call it periodically like this :

```
function showdate(){

    var date = new Date();

    var day = date.getDay();

    var name = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][day];

    document.getElementById("date").textContent = name;

        console.log('show date');
}

setInterval(showdate, 1000)
```

This way, the client will get the new date every second (where `1000` is in milliseconds). But you can change the time to any value (keep in mind it's in `ms`) that fit your needs.

You also can take a look at [**this example**](https://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/zvcrxae0/).

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showdate(){
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay();
    var name = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][day];
    document.getElementById("date").textContent = name;

  console.log('show date');
}
setInterval(showdate, 1000)

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
      i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    t = setTimeout(function() {
      startTime()
    }, 500);
}
startTime();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="date"></div>
<div id="time"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
// Show date every day at 12
function showdateEveryDayAt12() {
  setInterval(function() {
    showdate();
  }, 86400000);
}

// Show date at next 12, and call showdateEveryDayAt12()
function showdateAtNext12() {
  var now = new Date();
  var millisecondsTo12 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 12, 0, 0, 0) - now;

  setTimeout(function() {
    showdate();
    showdateEveryDayAt12();
  }, millisecondsTo12);
}

// Show date
function showdate() {
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var name = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"][day];

  document.getElementById("date").textContent = name;
}


// Show date now, at next 12 and every day at 12
showdate();
showdateAtNext12();
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
```

Comment: Imma try that later. 86400000 is 24 hours right? What if I start application at 18:00 it will get update in 18:00 next day right?

Comment: The function `showdateAtNext12()` will be executed at the next `12`.. and this will call the function `showdateEveryDayAt12()`

Comment: Sorry for my confusion but when I change 12 values to 24 to use 24H format it will be executed at next 24 hours right?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea

Comment: Thank you for that. I ll let know if that works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194808/discussion-between-yosvel-quintero-and-cabry).

Comment: @Cabry Good to help