# How would I setup a HTML page to have a new title each new day?

Tags: javascript, html

So my ultimate goal here is to have the site have a new title each day (24 hours).

I am not a very experienced program, but, I am aware something similar could be done with JS.

I saw this idea:

```
setInterval(function() {
    //change title
    //document.title = "Some new title";
}, 3000);
```

I'm not sure how I can take this idea above, which I do not fully understand and make it use, for example, a large array or predefined titles and select one at random each day.

Would it be possible to select the title out of another file or should I have them all in the JS file?  On the question just asked, should I have the JS code in the HTML file itself or referenced as a file like a CSS file?

I really appreciate any walkthrough/help I can get on this.  I hope your days are well all.

Comment: Do you expect most people using your site to have it open for 24 hours continuously?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery There was obviously no thought process about how people use the web.

Comment: In answer to your 1st two questions contained in one: (1) yes, (2) if you want. In answer to your 2nd two questions contained in one: (1) sure why not, (2) that works also. SO is not a _write some code for me for free site_. It's also not a _teach me an entire course on web technologies, so that I can answer my own simple questions about something that once I have the knowledge I would never consider doing_. It is **expected** that you have some basic knowledge of what you are trying to do and that you have **attempted** to do it. Voting to close.

Comment: No, I would expect they return on another day however.

Some websites such as wowhead.com a very popular website, already use similar ideas however.  Thank you @gforce301 for being snide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solved problem with running code once per day:
[Run code once a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741979/run-code-once-a-day)

When you will have a function that runs once per day, you just have to reference the title from DOM inside the function and define new title.

```
var titles = ["title1", "title2", "title3"];
var iterator = 0; // this variable should be incremented every day

// somewhere inside the function that runs once per day
document.title = titles[iterator];
```

There are 2 ways to import a script on html page.

Inline: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

External: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

U can even read external file (.txt e.g.) in js, you can look that up, but it's bit more complicated than this.

Comment: Hey, thank you, I will take a look at this and report back, thank you for your insight.

Comment: Outstanding, these references nailed it, thank you very much for your time.  I learn by doing so I really appreciate the assist.