# Javascript daily countdown not working

Tags: javascript, date

Hi i want this Javscript function to countdown how much time there is left untill the next day stars but i seem to get a problem when i want to automate it.

If i change this code

```
var eventDate = new Date();
eventDate.setDate(now.getDate() +1);
```

To this code it will work, but it is not automatic

```
var eventDate = new Date(2017, 03, 21);
```

So how can i make it automatic?

```
function countDown() {
    var now = new Date();
    var currentTime = now.getTime();
    var eventDate = new Date();
    eventDate.setDate(now.getDate() +1);

    var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();

    var remainingTime = eventTime - currentTime;

    var sekunder = Math.floor(remainingTime / 1000);
    var minutter = Math.floor(sekunder / 60);
    var timer = Math.floor(minutter / 60);

    sekunder %= 60;
    minutter %= 60;
    timer %= 24;

    sekunder = (sekunder < 10) ? "0" + sekunder : sekunder;
    minutter = (minutter < 10) ? "0" + minutter : minutter;
    timer = (timer < 10) ? "0" + timer : timer;

    var test = timer + ":" + minutter + ":" + sekunder;
    document.getElementById("countdownTimer").textContent = test;
    setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
}
countDown();
```

Also if anyone got the time, how do i make it countdown to my servers midnight time insted of the local computer time as Javascript will do?

Comment: `now.getDate() +1` Wouldn't this mean tomorrow at this exact time and not _untill the next day stars_

Comment: similar to [Determine minutes until midnight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583694/determine-minutes-until-midnight)

Comment: seems to [work](https://jsbin.com/suwivadava/edit?html,js,output) when using the answer linked by @PatrickBarr

Comment: To count down to your server midnight, send an ISO 8601 format string for midnight on your server, create a Date from it on the client and count down to it. There are plenty of questions and answers about that already.

Answer (score 0):

You can create event start date this way

```
var tomorrow = new Date();

tomorrow.setDate(now.getDate() +1);

var eventDate = new Date(tomorrow.getFullYear(), tomorrow.getMonth(), tomorrow.getDate());
```

and remove

```
eventDate.setDate(now.getDate() +1);
```

Comment: How does this fix the OP's issue? If the intention is to set the hours to zero, then `tomorrow.setHours(0,0,0,0)` will do that without creating a new Date.

Comment: Yes, the target is to set hours to zero