# javascript: I have subtracted two dates to get the difference between them, how do I find the number of months between the two dates?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference in Months between two dates in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Just don't know how to get the difference in moths between two time or date objects.

My current Code:

```
    var start_time = plot_data[0][0]; // first array selector gets the pair, second: the time
    var end_time = plot_data[plot_data.length - 1][0];
    var time_range = end_time - start_time;
```

this would be nice:

```
var diff_in_months = time_range.months()?
```

=D

Comment: few helpful links: http://ditio.net/2010/05/02/javascript-date-difference-calculation/ http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327429/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

Javascript Date object has several methods for this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp
if startTime and endTime are Date-objects:

```
var diff_in_Months = endTime.getMonth() - startTime.getMonth();
```

Taking years into account is bit more complicated.

```
var diff_in_Months = ( endTime.getFullYear()*12 + endTime.getMonth() ) - ( startTime.getFullYear()*12 + startTime.getMonth() );
```

I guess?