# Javascript DateDiff

Tags: javascript, date, datediff

I am having a problem with the DateDiff function. I am trying to figure out the Difference between two dates/times. I have read this posting ([What's the best way to calculate date difference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327429/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)) and I also looked at this tutorial (http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml) but I can't seem to get it.

Here is what I tried to get to work with no success. Could someone please tell me what I am doing and how I can simplify this. Seems a little over coded...?

```
//Set the two dates
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var currDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
var iniremDate = "8/10/2012";

//Show the dates subtracted
document.write('DateDiff is: ' + currDate - iniremDate);

//Try this function...
function DateDiff(date1, date2) {
    return date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
}

//Print the results of DateDiff
document.write (DateDiff(iniremDate, currDate);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first try does addition first and then subtraction. You cannot subtract strings anyway, so that yields `NaN`.

The second trry has no closing `)`. Apart from that, you're calling `getTime` on strings. You'd need to use `new Date(...).getTime()`. Note that you get the result in milliseconds when subtracting dates. You could format that by taking out full days/hours/etc.

Comment: As per you said it would show a negative value. Is this correct it seems correct because it shows the negative values.   document.write(new Date(iniremDate)-new Date(currDate));
  
  function DateDiff(date1, date2) {
      return date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
  }
   
  document.write (DateDiff(new Date(iniremDate),new Date(currDate)));

Comment: Since `iniremDate` is 10th of August and it's the 17th right now, you obviously get a negative value. If you want to subtract the opposite, just subtract `date1` from `date2`.

Comment: The returning value is -604800000 I take it that means it has passed that long ago in seconds?

Comment: @Frank G: That's in milliseconds. If you convert it to days it's indeed 7 days ago: `-604800000 / (24*60*60*1000) === -7`.

Comment: Yes, your correct thank you I was able to get it working thanks for the help. I posted a full working example below for others who might be looking for help with this to!!! Thanks :D

Answer (score 13):

Okay for those who would like a working example here is a simple DateDiff ex that tells date diff by day in a negative value (date passed already) or positive (date is coming).

EDIT: I updated this script so it will do the leg work for you and convert the results in to in this case a -10 which means the date has passed. Input your own dates for currDate and iniPastedDate and you should be good to go!!

```
//Set the two dates
var currentTime   = new Date()
var currDate      = currentTime.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + currentTime.getDate() + "/" + currentTime.getFullYear() //Todays Date - implement your own date here.
var iniPastedDate = "8/7/2012" //PassedDate - Implement your own date here.

//currDate = 8/17/12 and iniPastedDate = 8/7/12

function DateDiff(date1, date2) {
    var datediff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime(); //store the getTime diff - or +
    return (datediff / (24*60*60*1000)); //Convert values to -/+ days and return value      
}

//Write out the returning value should be using this example equal -10 which means 
//it has passed by ten days. If its positive the date is coming +10.    
document.write (DateDiff(new Date(iniPastedDate),new Date(currDate))); //Print the results...
```

Comment: Note that this is quite limited - `getDay` returns the day of the week so it's basically only usable if both dates are in the same week (`iniremDate = "8/8/2012"` would yield the same result).

Comment: @pimvdb what if you use getTime then does that work for any date?

Comment: `getTime` is not relative to the current week or something like that; it gives a unique number for each date so it's reliable for your needs. The only problem is that you'd need to convert the milliseconds difference into a days difference yourself.

Comment: I have to say it seems like every language doesn't ever have a good DateDiff and as important of a function as it is you would think they would have this covered for you... make life a little easier!

Comment: @pimvdb I updated the script now so it would do the leg work for people. Thanks for you help with this!! :)

Comment: @pimvdb well maybe this will help someone looking for it! It will at least point them in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

```
function setDateWeek(setDay){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - setDay); // <-- add this
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    return curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year;
}


setDateWeek(1);
```

Answer (score -3):

No need to include JQuery or any other third party library.

Specify your input date format in title tag.

HTML:

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="http://services.iperfect.net/js/IP_generalLib.js">
```

Use javascript function:

```
IP_dateDiff(strDate1,strDate2,strDateFormat,debug[true/false])

alert(IP_dateDiff('11-12-2014','12-12-2014','DD-MM-YYYY',false));
```

IP_dateDiff function will return number of days.