# Subtraction date between date input in text box and date now using JQUERY,Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have HTML code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#useDatePicker").mouseout(function{
        //$("#result").text() = $("#useDatePicker").text();
        alert(1);
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" name="frm" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="date" id="useDatePicker"/>
    <input type="text" name="result" id="result" />
</form>
```

**What I need:**

when the user select date from date Picker, it will subtract with date now automatic and the result will be in `<input type="text" name="result" id="result" />`

**Problem**

I have no concept with it.

Comment: `new Date()` will get you the current time as a Date object. `new Date(fullDate)` will get you the Date object for the supplied date.

Comment: `Date#valueOf()` will get you the Date`s value as a timestamp in milliseconds

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327429/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you can use onselect option of date picker of jquery ui

demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTKYZ/5/)

```
 $('#useDatePicker').datepicker({
onSelect: function (date) {

    var today = new Date();

    var result = DateDiff(today, new Date(date));

    $('#result').val(result);

}

});

function DateDiff(date1, date2) {
var diff = date1 - date2;
var num_years = diff / 31536000000;
var num_months = (diff % 31536000000) / 2628000000;
var num_days = ((diff % 31536000000) % 2628000000) / 86400000;

 return Math.floor(num_years) + "years " + Math.floor(num_months) + "months " +    Math.floor(num_days) + "days";
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer,but the result I want to get as `year month day` for example:`2year 3months 10days` after subtraction.Please help me to fix this.Thanks.

Comment: @PovNu i have updated the fiddle i think it achieves your result