# Compare SQL datetime to current date and time in TS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function that takes an array of type `any[]` and compares the `ExpiryDate` property with the current date and time. If the `ExpiryDate` property is bigger then the current date and time, then it's a valid passport in this case, otherwise the passport has expired

```
currentPassports: any[];
oldPassports: any[];
passports: any[];

processPassports(passports: any[]): void {
    var arrayLength = passports.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            if (passports[i].ExpiryDate > CurrentDateTime)
        // Add the object to currentPassports
            else
        // Add the object to expiredPassports 
    }
}
```

What is the best way to compare SQL datetime to the current time in TypeScript?
And how can I EXACTLY compare each object's ExpiryDate (also include Milliseconds in the comparison)

Note: `CurrentDateTime` is just a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if the SQL datetime coming in is already a date or if it is a string. If you do need to parse the SQL date, I have found Moment.js to be one of the easiest libraries to use.

If you need to get the current date and time in javascript just call, `new Date()`

If you need to compare the two dates, including milliseconds, follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/327458/5656858

Comment: I never head anything back about this one. If you think that I helped you at all with this, then feel free to mark this as the correct answer.