# How to calculate number of days between two dates?

Tags: javascript, date

For example, given two dates in input boxes:

```
<input id="first" value="1/1/2000"/>
<input id="second" value="1/1/2001"/>

<script>
  alert(datediff("day", first, second)); // what goes here?
</script>
```

How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?

Comment: 99% of the cases where the user asks for "number of days between two dates" what she doesn't understand is that she is trying to compare apples with pears. The problem becomes so simple if asked "How many DATES are there in a DATE RANGE?", Or how many squares I have to cross on the calendar. This leaves off time and daylight saving issues etc etc.The confusion is implied on us because of the datetime data structure which is pure nonsense. There is no such thing as datetime there is date and there is time, two very distinct objects in both nature and behavior

Comment: For a function that splits the difference into (whole) units of time, use the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53092438/3787376.

Comment: I feel this question should be deleted or at least marked "avoid" as most of the answers are either incorrect or dependent on various libraries.

Comment: @RobG libraries are the only option if JavaScript does not provide a built-in way to do it right.

Comment: @MCEmperor—hardly, the [top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/543152/257182) is just 3 lines of code, and two of those are for parsing.

Comment: @RobG Well, haven't you read the rest of that same answer? The poster calls the solution "quick and dirty". And also recommends a date and time API. Whilst I was talking about doing it *right*. And to me, the number of lines of code has nothing to do with doing it right.

Comment: @MC Emperor - You looked at the worlds quick and dirty and didn't actually look at whether the answer was correct.    It *is* correct, because at the end of the day we are measuring duration / intervals, and not doing a date calculation.  The date it says on our calendar, otoh, should be done with a library since that will include things like leap years and adjustments.

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler)

Answer (score 537, accepted):

Here is a **quick and dirty** implementation of `datediff`, as a proof of concept to solve the problem as presented in the question. It relies on the fact that you can get the elapsed milliseconds between two dates by subtracting them, which coerces them into their primitive number value (milliseconds since the start of 1970).

```js
/**
 * Take the difference between the dates and divide by milliseconds per day.
 * Round to nearest whole number to deal with DST.
 */
function datediff(first, second) {        
    return Math.round((second - first) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}

/**
 * new Date("dateString") is browser-dependent and discouraged, so we'll write
 * a simple parse function for U.S. date format (which does no error checking)
 */
function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/');
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0] - 1, mdy[1]);
}

alert(datediff(parseDate(first.value), parseDate(second.value)));
```

```html
<input id="first" value="1/1/2000"/>
<input id="second" value="1/1/2001"/>
```

You should be aware that the "normal" Date APIs (without "UTC" in the name) operate in the local timezone of the user's browser, so in general you could run into issues if your user is in a timezone that you don't expect, and your code will have to deal with Daylight Saving Time transitions. You should carefully read the documentation for the Date object and its methods, and for anything more complicated, strongly consider using a library that offers more safe and powerful APIs for date manipulation.

- [Numbers and Dates -- MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates)
- [`Date` -- MDN JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

<sub>Also, for illustration purposes, the snippet uses [named access on the `window` object](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) for brevity, but in production you should use standardized APIs like [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), or more likely, some UI framework.</sub>

Comment: I think Math.trunc() is more appropriate. Just in case someone uses more precise Date objects (i.e. including hours, minutes and seconds)

Comment: As the answer that's marked correct and highest voted (as of now), it's worth commenting that this answer doesn't correctly handle Daylight Savings Time. See Michael Liu's answer instead.

Comment: What does parseDate do exactly?

Comment: @osullic—this answer handles daylight saving with *Math.round*, however it does expect to be handed date only strings, not date and time.

Comment: @M98—it's a help function to ensure the date string is correctly parsed. It's very sensible to not rely on the Date constructor or Date.parse for parsing.

Comment: Just remember that the date is in US format in this example, i.e. MM/DD/YYYY. If you need the UK version, then you need to change the `parseDate` method to be: `return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[1], mdy[0]-1);`

Comment: This answer is from 11 years ago - at the time we didn't have a library that took care of this that could be trusted to do the right thin for all timezones with every calendar quirk, but we do now, so in 2020 the answer is most definitely not this, but "use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)" instead. No one should be rolling their own code for something this complex when there's a real solution.

Comment: Just use `new Date` for parsing dates. Any situation in which your `parseDate` function works correctly, using `new Date` will work as well in all browsers

Comment: It also does not correctly handle two dates on the same day.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans moment.js is an enormous library. Nobody should be adding such a big dependency for what amounts to a single line of code.

Comment: Did you forget to look at the date for that comment? Back in 2020 this wasn't a single line of code. Today, it is. And _that_ is why you shouldn't use moment.js anymore in 2024 (as per the moment.js README.md, which tells you to no longer use it).

Answer (score 267):

As of this writing, only one of the other answers correctly handles DST (daylight saving time) transitions. Here are the results on a system located in California:

```
                                        1/1/2013- 3/10/2013- 11/3/2013-
User       Formula                      2/1/2013  3/11/2013  11/4/2013  Result
---------  ---------------------------  --------  ---------  ---------  ---------
Miles                   (d2 - d1) / N   31        0.9583333  1.0416666  Incorrect
some         Math.floor((d2 - d1) / N)  31        0          1          Incorrect
fuentesjr    Math.round((d2 - d1) / N)  31        1          1          Correct
toloco     Math.ceiling((d2 - d1) / N)  31        1          2          Incorrect

N = 86400000
```

Although `Math.round` returns the correct results, I think it's somewhat clunky. Instead, by explicitly accounting for changes to the UTC offset when DST begins or ends, we can use exact arithmetic:

```
function treatAsUTC(date) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setMinutes(result.getMinutes() - result.getTimezoneOffset());
    return result;
}

function daysBetween(startDate, endDate) {
    var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return (treatAsUTC(endDate) - treatAsUTC(startDate)) / millisecondsPerDay;
}

alert(daysBetween($('#first').val(), $('#second').val()));
```

### Explanation

JavaScript date calculations are tricky because `Date` objects store times internally in UTC, not local time. For example, 3/10/2013 12:00 AM Pacific Standard Time (UTC-08:00) is stored as 3/10/2013 8:00 AM UTC, and 3/11/2013 12:00 AM Pacific Daylight Time (UTC-07:00) is stored as 3/11/2013 7:00 AM UTC. On this day, midnight to midnight local time is only 23 hours in UTC!

Although a day in local time can have more or less than 24 hours, a day in UTC is always exactly 24 hours.<sup>1</sup> The `daysBetween` method shown above takes advantage of this fact by first calling `treatAsUTC` to adjust both local times to midnight UTC, before subtracting and dividing.

<sup>1. JavaScript ignores leap seconds.</sup>

Comment: There is no need to use UTC, it's fine to just set the local hours to midnight (or the same value for both dates). The fractional day introduced by daylight saving is only ±0.04 at most (and in some places less), so it rounds out with *Math.round*. ;-) Relying on the Date constructor to parse strings is not a good idea. If you really want to use UTC values, parse the strings using `Date.UTC(...)` in the first place.

Comment: @RobG: As I stated in my answer: "Although Math.round returns the correct results, I think it's somewhat clunky. Instead, by explicitly accounting for changes to the UTC offset when DST begins or ends, we can use exact arithmetic."

Comment: Actually, the times you've represented as "incorrect" are, technically, correct. You aren't changing the DateTimes to UTC... you're just changing the time of each DateTime to get an artificial whole number. Rounding isn't "clunky"... it's exactly the correct approach here because that's what you're doing in your head anyways: you're rounding away the time portion (hours, minutes, seconds) and just trying to get a whole day number.

Answer (score 141):

The easiest way to get the difference between two dates:

```
var diff = Math.floor((Date.parse(str2) - Date.parse(str1)) / 86400000);
```

You get the difference days (or NaN if one or both could not be parsed). The parse date gived the result in milliseconds and to get it by day you have to divided it by `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`

If you want it divided by days, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds:

```
function dateDiff( str1, str2 ) {
    var diff = Date.parse( str2 ) - Date.parse( str1 ); 
    return isNaN( diff ) ? NaN : {
        diff : diff,
        ms : Math.floor( diff            % 1000 ),
        s  : Math.floor( diff /     1000 %   60 ),
        m  : Math.floor( diff /    60000 %   60 ),
        h  : Math.floor( diff /  3600000 %   24 ),
        d  : Math.floor( diff / 86400000        )
    };
}
```

Here is my refactored version of James version:

```
function mydiff(date1,date2,interval) {
    var second=1000, minute=second*60, hour=minute*60, day=hour*24, week=day*7;
    date1 = new Date(date1);
    date2 = new Date(date2);
    var timediff = date2 - date1;
    if (isNaN(timediff)) return NaN;
    switch (interval) {
        case "years": return date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear();
        case "months": return (
            ( date2.getFullYear() * 12 + date2.getMonth() )
            -
            ( date1.getFullYear() * 12 + date1.getMonth() )
        );
        case "weeks"  : return Math.floor(timediff / week);
        case "days"   : return Math.floor(timediff / day); 
        case "hours"  : return Math.floor(timediff / hour); 
        case "minutes": return Math.floor(timediff / minute);
        case "seconds": return Math.floor(timediff / second);
        default: return undefined;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad answer. Math.floor() will lose you a day when clocks go forwards in daylight savings. Math.round() will give the right answer in most situations but there's better options in other answer too.

Comment: @some Where do you see *James version*? Who's James?

Comment: @stomy Looks like that version was deleted-

Comment: Using `Math.abs` may meet your needs.

Answer (score 132):

I recommend using the moment.js library (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/).  It handles daylight savings time correctly and in general is great to work with.

Example:

```
var start = moment("2013-11-03");
var end = moment("2013-11-04");
end.diff(start, "days")
1
```

Comment: Just as a warning while momentjs is great, it is quite a large dependency

Answer (score 127):

The following solutions will assume these variables are available in the code:

```js
const startDate  = '2020-01-01';
const endDate    = '2020-03-15';
```

---

### Native JS

Steps:

1. Set start date
2. Set end date
3. Calculate difference
4. Convert milliseconds to days

```js
const diffInMs   = new Date(endDate) - new Date(startDate)
const diffInDays = diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

##### Comment:

I know this is not part of your questions but in general, I would not recommend doing any date calculation or manipulation in vanilla JavaScript and rather use a library like [date-fns](https://date-fns.org), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) or [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) for it due to many edge cases.

This vanilla JavaScript answer calculates the days as a decimal number. Also, it could run into edge cases when working with Daylight Savings Time

---

### Using a Library

##### - Date-fns

```js
const differenceInDays = require('date-fns/differenceInDays');
const diffInDays = differenceInDays(new Date(endDate), new Date(startDate));
```

documentation: https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/differenceInDays

#### - Luxon

```js
const { DateTime } = require('luxon');
const diffInDays = DateTime.fromISO(endDate).diff(DateTime.fromISO(startDate), 'days').toObject().days;
```

documentation: https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimediff

#### - Moment.js

```js
const moment = require('moment');
const diffInDays = moment(endDate).diff(moment(startDate), 'days');
```

documentation: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

---

[Examples on RunKit](https://runkit.com/marcobiedermann/5f573e211e85e7001a37ab00)

Comment: I appreciate answers like these: short, simple and no random dependencies required! Cheers.

Comment: Is it just me that has `timeDiff`returned in the negative? Shouldn't `timeDiff` be `(new Date(endDate)) - (new Date(startDate));` ?

Comment: @feyisayo-sonubi depends in which order you pass in you start and end date.
In this example `(new Date('2017-11-08')) - (new Date('2017-10-01')) // 3283200000 `

Comment: `const timeDiff = +(new Date(start)) - +(new Date(end));`

Comment: Great.  Although I prefer `return (Date.UTC(yr2, mo2-1, dy2) - Date.UTC(yr1, mo1-1, dy1)) / 86400000;`

Comment: if Typescript giving error checkout @BenRacicot comment.

Comment: The remark "Also, it could run into edge cases when working with Daylight Savings Time" makes this answer worthless. That said, I don't think it will actually run into any issues because `new Date('2020-01-01')` is midnight UTC and UTC doesn't have DST.

Answer (score 44):

I would go ahead and [grab this small utility](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230194804/http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/source.html) and in it you will find functions to this for you. Here's a short example:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var minutes = 1000*60;
            var hours = minutes*60;
            var days = hours*24;

            var foo_date1 = getDateFromFormat("02/10/2009", "M/d/y");
            var foo_date2 = getDateFromFormat("02/12/2009", "M/d/y");
            
            var diff_date = Math.round((foo_date2 - foo_date1)/days);
            alert("Diff date is: " + diff_date );
        </script>
```

Comment: The provided link for the utility is dead.

Answer (score 17):

Using Moment.js

```js
var future = moment('05/02/2015');
var start = moment('04/23/2015');
var d = future.diff(start, 'days'); // 9
console.log(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: moment.js is really handy for things like YTD diff counts


`var now = moment(), yearStart = moment().startOf('year');

var ytdDays = now.diff(yearStart, 'days'); // this can be years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, and seconds

console.log(ytdDays);`

more here: https://momentjs.com

Answer (score 12):

To Calculate days between 2 given dates you can use the following code.Dates I use here are Jan 01 2016 and Dec 31 2016

```js
var day_start = new Date("Jan 01 2016");
var day_end = new Date("Dec 31 2016");
var total_days = (day_end - day_start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.round(total_days);
```

```html
<h3>DAYS BETWEEN GIVEN DATES</h3>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 12):

Try This

```js
let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)

const startDate  = '2021-04-15';
const endDate    = today;

const diffInMs   = new Date(endDate) - new Date(startDate)
const diffInDays = diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);


alert( diffInDays  );
```

Comment: same as much older answers

Answer (score 11):

Date values in JS are datetime values.

So, direct date computations are inconsistent:

```
(2013-11-05 00:00:00) - (2013-11-04 10:10:10) < 1 day
```

for example we need to convert de 2nd date:

```
(2013-11-05 00:00:00) - (2013-11-04 00:00:00) = 1 day
```

the method could be truncate the mills in both dates:

```js
var date1 = new Date('2013/11/04 00:00:00');
var date2 = new Date('2013/11/04 10:10:10'); //less than 1
var start = Math.floor(date1.getTime() / (3600 * 24 * 1000)); //days as integer from..
var end = Math.floor(date2.getTime() / (3600 * 24 * 1000)); //days as integer from..
var daysDiff = end - start; // exact dates
console.log(daysDiff);

date2 = new Date('2013/11/05 00:00:00'); //1

var start = Math.floor(date1.getTime() / (3600 * 24 * 1000)); //days as integer from..
var end = Math.floor(date2.getTime() / (3600 * 24 * 1000)); //days as integer from..
var daysDiff = end - start; // exact dates
console.log(daysDiff);
```

Answer (score 10):

Better to get rid of DST, Math.ceil, Math.floor etc. by using UTC times:

```
var firstDate = Date.UTC(2015,01,2);
var secondDate = Date.UTC(2015,04,22);
var diff = Math.abs((firstDate.valueOf() 
    - secondDate.valueOf())/(24*60*60*1000));
```

This example gives difference 109 days. `24*60*60*1000` is one day in milliseconds.

Comment: It's worth to add that if you want current date in UTC you can do this: `var now = new Date(); var utcNow = Date.UTC(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate())`

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to calculate a full proof days difference between two dates resting across different TZs using the following formula:

```js
var start = new Date('10/3/2015');
var end = new Date('11/2/2015');
var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
console.log(days);
// actually its 30 ; but due to daylight savings will show 31.0xxx
// which you need to offset as below
days = days - (end.getTimezoneOffset() - start.getTimezoneOffset()) / (60 * 24);
console.log(days);
```

Answer (score 8):

I found this question when I want do some calculate on two date, but the date have hours and minutes value, I modified @michael-liu 's answer to fit my requirement, and it passed my test.

diff days `2012-12-31 23:00` and `2013-01-01 01:00` should equal 1. (2 hour)
diff days `2012-12-31 01:00` and `2013-01-01 23:00` should equal 1. (46 hour)

```
function treatAsUTC(date) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setMinutes(result.getMinutes() - result.getTimezoneOffset());
    return result;
}

var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
function diffDays(startDate, endDate) {
    return Math.floor(treatAsUTC(endDate) / millisecondsPerDay) - Math.floor(treatAsUTC(startDate) / millisecondsPerDay);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it seems to answer the question with a relatively simple bit of code, I think.  Can't you use something like this:

```
function dayDiff(startdate, enddate) {
  var dayCount = 0;

  while(enddate >= startdate) {
    dayCount++;
    startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate() + 1);
  }

return dayCount; 
}
```

This is assuming you are passing date objects as parameters.

Answer (score 7):

```
var start= $("#firstDate").datepicker("getDate");
var end= $("#SecondDate").datepicker("getDate");
var days = (end- start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
 alert(Math.round(days));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AravindhGopi/tbwa1m8c/4/) example :)

Answer (score 7):

#### One-Liner and small

```js
const diff=(e,t)=>Math.floor((new Date(e).getTime()-new Date(t).getTime())/1000*60*60*24);

// or

const diff=(e,t)=>Math.floor((new Date(e)-new Date(t))/864e5);

// or

const diff=(a,b)=>(new Date(a)-new Date(b))/864e5|0; 

// use
diff('1/1/2001', '1/1/2000')
```

#### For TypeScript

```js
const diff = (from: string, to: string) => Math.floor((new Date(from).getTime() - new Date(to).getTime()) / 86400000);
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use **ceil** instead of **floor**, round will work but it isn't the right operation.

```
function dateDiff(str1, str2){
    var diff = Date.parse(str2) - Date.parse(str1); 
    return isNaN(diff) ? NaN : {
        diff: diff,
        ms: Math.ceil(diff % 1000),
        s: Math.ceil(diff / 1000 % 60),
        m: Math.ceil(diff / 60000 % 60),
        h: Math.ceil(diff / 3600000 % 24),
        d: Math.ceil(diff / 86400000)
    };
}
```

Comment: Days can have more than 24 hours and minutes can have more than 60 seconds. Using Math.ceil() would overcount in these cases.

Answer (score 5):

```js
Date.prototype.days = function(to) {
  return Math.abs(Math.floor(to.getTime() / (3600 * 24 * 1000)) - Math.floor(this.getTime() / (3600 * 24 * 1000)))
}


console.log(new Date('2014/05/20').days(new Date('2014/05/23'))); // 3 days

console.log(new Date('2014/05/23').days(new Date('2014/05/20'))); // 3 days
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
function timeDifference(date1, date2) {
  var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60; // hours*minutes*seconds
  var oneHour = 60 * 60; // minutes*seconds
  var oneMinute = 60; // 60 seconds
  var firstDate = date1.getTime(); // convert to milliseconds
  var secondDate = date2.getTime(); // convert to milliseconds
  var seconds = Math.round(Math.abs(firstDate - secondDate) / 1000); //calculate the diffrence in seconds
  // the difference object
  var difference = {
    "days": 0,
    "hours": 0,
    "minutes": 0,
    "seconds": 0,
  }
  //calculate all the days and substract it from the total
  while (seconds >= oneDay) {
    difference.days++;
    seconds -= oneDay;
  }
  //calculate all the remaining hours then substract it from the total
  while (seconds >= oneHour) {
    difference.hours++;
    seconds -= oneHour;
  }
  //calculate all the remaining minutes then substract it from the total 
  while (seconds >= oneMinute) {
    difference.minutes++;
    seconds -= oneMinute;
  }
  //the remaining seconds :
  difference.seconds = seconds;
  //return the difference object
  return difference;
}
console.log(timeDifference(new Date(2017,0,1,0,0,0),new Date()));
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @N.Belhadj you can replace all those while loops with simple div and mod (%) operations

Answer (score 4):

What about using [formatDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/%24.datepicker.formatDate) from DatePicker widget? You could use it to convert the dates in timestamp format (milliseconds since 01/01/1970) and then do a simple subtraction.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in Angular. I do the copy because else he will overwrite the first date. Both dates must have time 00:00:00 (obviously)

```
 /*
* Deze functie gebruiken we om het aantal dagen te bereken van een booking.
* */
$scope.berekenDagen = function ()
{
    $scope.booking.aantalDagen=0;

    /*De loper is gelijk aan de startdag van je reservatie.
     * De copy is nodig anders overschijft angular de booking.van.
     * */
    var loper = angular.copy($scope.booking.van);

    /*Zolang de reservatie beschikbaar is, doorloop de weekdagen van je start tot einddatum.*/
    while (loper < $scope.booking.tot) {
        /*Tel een dag op bij je loper.*/
        loper.setDate(loper.getDate() + 1);
        $scope.booking.aantalDagen++;
    }

    /*Start datum telt natuurlijk ook mee*/
    $scope.booking.aantalDagen++;
    $scope.infomsg +=" aantal dagen: "+$scope.booking.aantalDagen;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have two unix timestamps, you can use this function (made a little more verbose for the sake of clarity):

```
// Calculate number of days between two unix timestamps
// ------------------------------------------------------------
var daysBetween = function(timeStampA, timeStampB) {
    var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours * minutes * seconds * milliseconds
    var firstDate = new Date(timeStampA * 1000);
    var secondDate = new Date(timeStampB * 1000);
    var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
    return diffDays;
};
```

Example:

```
daysBetween(1096580303, 1308713220); // 2455
```

Answer (score 4):

Be careful when **using milliseconds**.

The **date.getTime()** returns milliseconds and doing **math operation with milliseconds requires to include**

- Daylight Saving Time (DST)
- checking if both dates have the same time (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
- make sure what behavior of days diff is required: 19 September 2016 - 29 September 2016 = 1 or 2 days difference?

The example from comment above is the best solution I found so far
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11252167/2091095 . But use **+1** to its result if you want the to count all days involved.

```
function treatAsUTC(date) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setMinutes(result.getMinutes() - result.getTimezoneOffset());
    return result;
}

function daysBetween(startDate, endDate) {
    var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return (treatAsUTC(endDate) - treatAsUTC(startDate)) / millisecondsPerDay;
}

var diff = daysBetween($('#first').val(), $('#second').val()) + 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

The simple way to calculate days between two dates is to remove both of their time component i.e. setting hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 and then subtracting their time and diving it with milliseconds worth of one day.

```
var firstDate= new Date(firstDate.setHours(0,0,0,0));
var secondDate= new Date(secondDate.setHours(0,0,0,0));
var timeDiff = firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime();
var diffDays =timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
```

Comment: problem with your solution is, you are assuming firstDate and secondDate to be dates which then there is no need to change them to date again, and if they are not date *which are not) you'll get error on setHours. to correct this, you need to move setHours out of `new Date`

Answer (score 3):

I used below code to experiment the posting date functionality for a news post.I calculate the minute or hour or day or year based on the posting date and current date.

```
var startDate= new Date("Mon Jan 01 2007 11:00:00");
var endDate  =new Date("Tue Jan 02 2007 12:50:00");
var timeStart = startDate.getTime();
var timeEnd = endDate.getTime();
var yearStart = startDate.getFullYear();
var yearEnd   = endDate.getFullYear();
if(yearStart == yearEnd)
 {
  var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart; 
  var secDiff = hourDiff / 1000;
  var minDiff = hourDiff / 60 / 1000; 
  var hDiff = hourDiff / 3600 / 1000; 
  var myObj = {};
  myObj.hours = Math.floor(hDiff);
  myObj.minutes = minDiff  
  if(myObj.hours >= 24)
   {
    console.log(Math.floor(myObj.hours/24) + "day(s) ago")
   } 
 else if(myObj.hours>0)
  {
   console.log(myObj.hours +"hour(s) ago")
  }
 else
  {
   console.log(Math.abs(myObj.minutes) +"minute(s) ago")
  }
}
else
{
var yearDiff = yearEnd - yearStart;
console.log( yearDiff +" year(s) ago");
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code and you solved the problem, just pasting code is considered a bad answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoScabbiolo,@Michael Parker for the comments.Since i am new to Stackoverflow in terms of answering,I was not aware of how the solution should be proivided

Answer (score 3):

if you wanna have an DateArray with dates try this:

```
<script>
        function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
        var dateArray = new Array();
        var currentDate = moment(startDate);
        dateArray.push( moment(currentDate).format('L'));

        var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
        while (dateArray[dateArray.length -1] != stopDate._i) {
            dateArray.push( moment(currentDate).format('L'));
            currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
        }
        return dateArray;
      }
</script>
```

[DebugSnippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIg1o.png)

Answer (score 3):

```
function formatDate(seconds, dictionary) {
    var foo = new Date;
    var unixtime_ms = foo.getTime();
    var unixtime = parseInt(unixtime_ms / 1000);
    var diff = unixtime - seconds;
    var display_date;
    if (diff <= 0) {
        display_date = dictionary.now;
    } else if (diff < 60) {
        if (diff == 1) {
            display_date = diff + ' ' + dictionary.second;
        } else {
            display_date = diff + ' ' + dictionary.seconds;
        }
    } else if (diff < 3540) {
        diff = Math.round(diff / 60);
        if (diff == 1) {
            display_date = diff + ' ' + dictionary.minute;
        } else {
            display_date = diff + ' ' + dictionary.minutes;
        }
    } else if (diff < 82800) {
        diff = Math.round(diff / 3600);
        if (diff == 1) {
            display_date = diff + ' ' + dictionary.hour;
        } else {
            display_date = diff + ' ' + dictionary.hours;
        }
    } else {
        diff = Math.round(diff / 86400);
        if (diff == 1) {
            display_date = diff + ' ' + dictionary.day;
        } else {
            display_date = diff + ' ' + dictionary.days;
        }
    }
    return display_date;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A Better Solution by

> Ignoring time part

it will return 0 if both the dates are same.

```js
function dayDiff(firstDate, secondDate) {
  firstDate = new Date(firstDate);
  secondDate = new Date(secondDate);
  if (!isNaN(firstDate) && !isNaN(secondDate)) {
    firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); //ignore time part
    secondDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); //ignore time part
    var dayDiff = secondDate - firstDate;
    dayDiff = dayDiff / 86400000; // divide by milisec in one day
    console.log(dayDiff);
  } else {
    console.log("Enter valid date.");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=datetime]').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });
  $("#button").click(function() {
    dayDiff($('#first').val(), $('#second').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="datetime" id="first" value="12/28/2016" />
<input type="datetime" id="second" value="12/28/2017" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="Calculate">
```

Comment: This is perfect. By Ignoring the time you can get the actual day difference.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, easy, and sophisticated. This function will be called in every 1 sec to update time.

```
const year = (new Date().getFullYear());
const bdayDate = new Date("04,11,2019").getTime(); //mmddyyyy

// countdown
let timer = setInterval(function () {

    // get today's date
    const today = new Date().getTime();

    // get the difference
    const diff = bdayDate - today;

    // math
    let days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same question, and coming from a Java world, I immediately started to search for a JSR 310 implementation for JavaScript. JSR 310 is a Date and Time API for Java (standard shipped as of Java 8). I think the API is very well designed.

Fortunately, there is a direct port to Javascript, called [**js-joda**](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/).

First, include js-joda in the `<head>`:

```html
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-joda/1.11.0/js-joda.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-piLlO+P2f15QHjUv0DEXBd4HvkL03Orhi30Ur5n1E4Gk2LE4BxiBAP/AD+dxhxpW66DiMY2wZqQWHAuS53RFDg=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then simply do this:

```js
let date1 = JSJoda.LocalDate.of(2020, 12, 1);
let date2 = JSJoda.LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 1);
let daysBetween = JSJoda.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);
```

Now `daysBetween` contains the number of days between. Note that the end date is *exclusive*.

Answer (score 2):

```
 // JavaScript / NodeJs answer  
   let startDate = new Date("2022-09-19");
   let endDate = new Date("2022-09-26");

   let difference = startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime();
   
    console.log(difference);

   let TotalDiffDays = Math.ceil(difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
   console.log(TotalDiffDays + " days :) ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I took some inspiration from other answers and made the inputs have automatic sanitation. I hope this works well as an improvement over other answers.

I also recommend the use of `<input type="date">` fields which would help validate user inputs.

```js
//use best practices by labeling your constants.
let MS_PER_SEC = 1000
  , SEC_PER_HR = 60 * 60
  , HR_PER_DAY = 24
  , MS_PER_DAY = MS_PER_SEC * SEC_PER_HR * HR_PER_DAY
;

//let's assume we get Date objects as arguments, otherwise return 0.
function dateDiffInDays(date1Time, date2Time) {
    if (!date1Time || !date2Time) return 0;
    return Math.round((date2Time - date1Time) / MS_PER_DAY);
}

function getUTCTime(dateStr) {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  // If use 'Date.getTime()' it doesn't compute the right amount of days
  // if there is a 'day saving time' change between dates
  return Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
}


function calcInputs() {
  let date1 = document.getElementById("date1")
    , date2 = document.getElementById("date2")
    , resultSpan = document.getElementById("result")
  ;
  if (date1.value && date2.value && resultSpan) {
    //remove non-date characters
    console.log(getUTCTime(date1.value));
    let date1Time = getUTCTime(date1.value)
      , date2Time = getUTCTime(date2.value)
      , result = dateDiffInDays(date1Time, date2Time)
    ;
    resultSpan.innerHTML = result + " days";
  }
}
window.onload = function() { calcInputs(); };

//some code examples
console.log(dateDiffInDays(new Date("1/15/2019"), new Date("1/30/2019")));
console.log(dateDiffInDays(new Date("1/15/2019"), new Date("2/30/2019")));
console.log(dateDiffInDays(new Date("1/15/2000"), new Date("1/15/2019")));
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date1" value="2000-01-01" onchange="calcInputs();" />
<input type="date" id="date2" value="2022-01-01" onchange="calcInputs();"/>
Result: <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Instead of using 'date1.getTime()' and 'date2.getTime()' I use 'Date.UTC' to prevent difference between dates that does not belong to the same day saving time (i.e. March 10, 2021 and March 16, 2021) 
  
the following function may help:
  
```function getUTCTime(date) {
        // If use 'Date.getTime()' it doesn't compute the right amount of days
        // if there is a 'day saving time' change between dates
        return Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
    }```

Answer (score 1):

The daylight saving issue is invalidating quite a few answers here. I would use a helper function to get a unique day number for a given date -- by using the `UTC` method:

```js
const dayNumber = a => Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate()) / (24*60*60*1000);
const daysBetween = (a, b) => dayNumber(b) - dayNumber(a);

// Testing it
const start = new Date(1000, 0, 1); // 1 January 1000
const end   = new Date(3000, 0, 1); // 1 January 3000
let current = new Date(start);
for (let days = 0; current < end; days++) {
    const diff = daysBetween(start, current);
    if (diff !== days) throw "test failed";
    current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1); // move current date one day forward
}
console.log("tests succeeded");
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest answer, accounting for time of day and leap years, boils down to five lines of code. You only need three lines of code if know that your entries will never have a time component.

```
  date1 = new Date("1/1/2000");
  date2 = new Date("1/1/2001");
  date1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // this line accounts for date strings that have time components
  date2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // this too
  daysBetween = Math.round((date2 - date1) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

I've included a fully documented function called daysDiff that accepts JavaScript date objects and throws errors if the parameters are malformed.

```
/**
 * Calculate the number of days between two dates, taking into account possible leap years.
 * Returns a positive or negative integer.
 *
 * @param {Date} date1 - The earlier of the two dates.
 * @param {Date} date2 - The later of the two dates.
 * @throws {TypeError} - If either dateOne or dateTwo is not a valid Date object.
 * @returns {number}   - Integer number of days between date1 and date2.
*/
function daysDiff(date1, date2) {
  // Ensure date1 and date2 are valid Date objects
  if (!(date1 instanceof Date) || !(date2 instanceof Date)) {
      throw new TypeError('Both date1 and date2 must be valid Date objects.');
  }

  const millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  
  // Reset time components to midnight to consistent days between without worrying about times.
  date1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  date2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  
  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds and convert to days
  return Math.round((date2 - date1) / millisecondsPerDay);
}

// accounts for leap year
console.log(daysDiff(new Date("1/1/2024"), new Date("4/30/2024")));

// returns the number of days between today and Jan 1, 2023
console.log(daysDiff(new Date("1/1/2023"), new Date()));

// returns a negative number as date1 is bigger than date2
console.log(daysDiff(new Date("1/30/2024"), new Date("1/1/2024")));

// ignores the time component so will return same result any time of day
console.log(daysDiff(new Date("1/30/2024 13:40:00", new Date())));

// throws an error because date1, while true, isn't a date.`
console.log(daysDiff("frogs are great", new Date()));
```

Comment: How is "subtract one date from another" any different than the other 2 pages of answers here, including the [almost 15 year old](https://stackoverflow.com/a/543152/1255289) accepted answer?

Comment: @miken32 My answer is more generic. The accepted answer provides no easy way to accommodate something as simple as today's date Date(). The time component will lead to inconsistent results. The closest answer to mine is from Sumit Joshi, with two upvotes which I missed the first time going through this.  The only difference between his and mine is that mine is better documented. I'll pull mine if it's too redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UnderscoreJS for formatting and calculating difference.

**Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/sumitridhal/8sv94msp/

```js
 var startDate = moment("2016-08-29T23:35:01");
var endDate = moment("2016-08-30T23:35:01");  
  

console.log(startDate);
console.log(endDate);

var resultHours = endDate.diff(startDate, 'hours', true);

document.body.innerHTML = "";
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resultHours));
```

```css
body { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using moment will be much easier in this case, You could try this:

```
    let days = moment(yourFirstDateString).diff(moment(yourSecondDateString), 'days');
```

It will give you integer value like 1,2,5,0etc so you can easily use condition check like:

```
if(days < 1) {
```

Also, one more thing is you can get more accurate result of the time difference (in decimals like 1.2,1.5,0.7etc) to get this kind of result use this syntax:

```
let days = moment(yourFirstDateString).diff(moment(yourSecondDateString), 'days', true);
```

Let me know if you have any further query

Answer (score 0):

The elephant in the room is that there's no single right answer!

If you just want the number of 24 hour periods between 2 dates then just subtract them, divide by 86400000, round up or down depending on your personal requirement and you're done.

If you want the number of calendar days it depends what time zone you're in: Say it's 11pm and you're in Bangkok, in 2 hours time it will be a different day for you, but for someone in LA it will be the same day.

Only if you're sure that (a) both the dates you're comparing (b) the timezone of your JavaScript instance (c) the person who wants to know the answer, are all in the same time zone, then you can do the calculation using local times.

In all other cases you need to think more carefully about what you're trying to achieve. For instance if one of the input dates is in Bangkok and the other is in LA then the number of days difference could still be 1 even if the two input values are identical.

In my case I don't know the time zone of either or the input dates or the person who's reading the output, so I decided to calculate what the number of calendar days would be in UTC like this:

```
(
    Date.UTC(d1.getUTCFullYear(), d1.getUTCMonth(), d1.getUTCDate()) 
    -
    Date.UTC(d2.getUTCFullYear(), d2.getUTCMonth(), d2.getUTCDate())
) / 86400000
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   function validateDate() {
        // get dates from input fields
        var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
        var endDate = $("#endDate").val();
        var sdate = startDate.split("-");
        var edate = endDate.split("-");
        var diffd = (edate[2] - sdate[2]) + 1;
        var leap = [ 0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ];
        var nonleap = [ 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ];
        if (sdate[0] > edate[0]) {
            alert("Please enter End Date Year greater than Start Date Year");
            document.getElementById("endDate").value = "";
            diffd = "";
        } else if (sdate[1] > edate[1]) {
            alert("Please enter End Date month greater than Start Date month");
            document.getElementById("endDate").value = "";
            diffd = "";
        } else if (sdate[2] > edate[2]) {
            alert("Please enter End Date greater than Start Date");
            document.getElementById("endDate").value = "";
            diffd = "";
        } else {
            if (sdate[0] / 4 == 0) {
                while (sdate[1] < edate[1]) {
                    diffd = diffd + leap[sdate[1]++];
                }
            } else {
                while (sdate[1] < edate[1]) {
                    diffd = diffd + nonleap[sdate[1]++];
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("numberOfDays").value = diffd;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Bookmarklet version of other answers, prompting you for both dates:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var d = new Date(prompt("First Date or leave blank for today?") || Date.now());
    prompt("Days Between", Math.round(
        Math.abs(
            (d.getTime() - new Date(prompt("Date 2")).getTime())
                /(24*60*60*1000)
             )
        ));
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer, based on another one (link at end), is about the difference between two dates.
You can see how it works because it's simple, also it includes splitting the difference into
units of time (a function that I made) and converting to UTC to stop time zone problems.

```js
function date_units_diff(a, b, unit_amounts) {
    var split_to_whole_units = function (milliseconds, unit_amounts) {
        // unit_amounts = list/array of amounts of milliseconds in a
        // second, seconds in a minute, etc., for example "[1000, 60]".
        time_data = [milliseconds];
        for (i = 0; i < unit_amounts.length; i++) {
            time_data.push(parseInt(time_data[i] / unit_amounts[i]));
            time_data[i] = time_data[i] % unit_amounts[i];
        }; return time_data.reverse();
    }; if (unit_amounts == undefined) {
        unit_amounts = [1000, 60, 60, 24];
    };
    var utc_a = new Date(a.toUTCString());
    var utc_b = new Date(b.toUTCString());
    var diff = (utc_b - utc_a);
    return split_to_whole_units(diff, unit_amounts);
}

// Example of use:
var d = date_units_diff(new Date(2010, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), new Date()).slice(0,-2);
document.write("In difference: 0 days, 1 hours, 2 minutes.".replace(
   /0|1|2/g, function (x) {return String( d[Number(x)] );} ));
```

### How my code above works

A date/time difference, as milliseconds, can be calculated using the [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object:

```javascript
var a = new Date(); // Current date now.
var b = new Date(2010, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Start of 2010.

var utc_a = new Date(a.toUTCString());
var utc_b = new Date(b.toUTCString());
var diff = (utc_b - utc_a); // The difference as milliseconds.
```

Then to work out the number of seconds in that difference, divide it by 1000 to convert
milliseconds to seconds, then change the result to an integer (whole number) to remove
the milliseconds (fraction part of that decimal): `var seconds = parseInt(diff/1000)`.
Also, I could get longer units of time using the same process, for example:
 - (whole) *minutes*, dividing *seconds* by 60 and changing the result to an integer,
 - *hours*, dividing *minutes* by 60 and changing the result to an integer.

I created a function for doing that process of splitting the difference into
whole units of time, named `split_to_whole_units`, with this demo:

```javascript
console.log(split_to_whole_units(72000, [1000, 60]));
// -> [1,12,0] # 1 (whole) minute, 12 seconds, 0 milliseconds.
```

*This answer is based on [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1968175/3787376).*

Answer (score -1):

I only got two timestamps in millisecond, so I have to do some extra steps with moment.js to get the days between.

```
const getDaysDiff = (fromTimestamp, toTimestamp) => {
    // set timezone offset with utcOffset if needed
    let fromDate = moment(fromTimestamp).utcOffset(8);
    let toDate = moment(toTimestamp).utcOffset(8);
    // get the start moment of the day
    fromDate.set({'hour':0, 'minute': 0, 'second': 0, 'millisecond': 0});
    toDate.set({'hour':0, 'minute': 0, 'second': 0, 'millisecond': 0});
    let diffDays = toDate.diff(fromDate, 'days');

    return diffDays;
}

getDaysDiff(1528889400000, 1528944180000)// 1
```

Answer (score -1):

A contribution, for date before 1970-01-01 and after 2038-01-19

```
function DateDiff(aDate1, aDate2) {
  let dDay = 0;
  this.isBissexto = (aYear) => {
    return (aYear % 4 == 0 && aYear % 100 != 0) || (aYear % 400 == 0);
  };
  this.getDayOfYear = (aDate) => {
    let count = 0;
    for (let m = 0; m < aDate.getUTCMonth(); m++) {
      count += m == 1 ? this.isBissexto(aDate.getUTCFullYear()) ? 29 : 28 : /(3|5|8|10)/.test(m) ? 30 : 31;
    }
    count += aDate.getUTCDate();
    return count;
  };
  this.toDays = () => {
    return dDay;
  };
  (() => {
    let startDate = aDate1.getTime() <= aDate2.getTime() ? new Date(aDate1.toISOString()) : new Date(aDate2.toISOString());
    let endDate = aDate1.getTime() <= aDate2.getTime() ? new Date(aDate2.toISOString()) : new Date(aDate1.toISOString());
    while (startDate.getUTCFullYear() != endDate.getUTCFullYear()) {
      dDay += (this.isBissexto(startDate.getFullYear())? 366 : 365) - this.getDayOfYear(startDate) + 1;
      startDate = new Date(startDate.getUTCFullYear()+1, 0, 1);
    }
    dDay += this.getDayOfYear(endDate) - this.getDayOfYear(startDate);
  })();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**This is bit different answer if we want to calculate our age**

```
    {
      birthday: 'April 22, 1993',
      names: {
        first: 'Keith',
        last: 'Buckley'
      }
    },
    {
      birthday: 'January 3, 1975',
      names: {
        first: 'Larry',
        last: 'Heep'
      }
    },
    {
      birthday: 'February 12, 1944',
      names: {
        first: 'Linda',
        last: 'Bermeer'
      }
    }
  ];
const cleanPeople = people.map(function ({birthday, names:{first, last}}) {
      // birthday, age, fullName;
      const now = new Date();
      var age =  Math.floor(( Date.parse(now) - Date.parse(birthday)) / 31536000000);
      return {
        age,
        fullName:`${first} ${last}`
      }
    });
    console.log(cleanPeople);
    console.table(cleanPeople);
```