# Javascript equivalent of php's strtotime()?

Tags: javascript, date

In PHP, you can easily convert an English textual datetime description into a proper date with `strtotime()`.

Is there anything similar in Javascript?

Comment: For parsing from the format dd.mm.yyyy, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-datetime-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found [this article](http://w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp) and tried the tutorial. Basically, you can use the date constructor to parse a date, then write get the seconds from the `getTime()` method

```
var d=new Date("October 13, 1975 11:13:00");
document.write(d.getTime() + " milliseconds since 1970/01/01");
```

Does this work?

Comment: It seems that I does not work it the date is formatted in d.m.Y format.

Comment: -1. This only covers RFC 822 or ISO 8601 formatted dates, but `strtotime()` supports many other formats.

Comment: This may happen to satisfy the OP's use case, but it is a technically incorrect, invalid answer to the question. See (and please upvote) Westy92's answer.

Comment: Just a quick note to be careful when using this built-in string parsing.  Javascript will handle timezones differently for partial ISO date strings.  The code `new Date('2021-04-01')` will have a time of midnight with a UTC timezone where as the date `new Date('04/01/2021')` will be created with a time of midnight in the local timezone. This difference can create subtle bugs in a program if you're parsing dates with both string formats.

Answer (score 69):

There is not. The closest built-in option is `Date.parse()`, which parses [a very limited subset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) of what `strtotime()` can:

```
var ts = Date.parse("2010-10-29");
```

It's worth noting that this function returns milliseconds instead of seconds, so you need to divide the result by 1000 to get an equivalent value to PHP's function.

Comment: Nope; this works very different than php strtotime, none of the examples of the php documentation work, not a single one `strtotime("now");
strtotime("10 September 2000");
strtotime("+1 day");
strtotime("+1 week");
strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds");
strtotime("next Thursday");
strtotime("last Monday");`

Comment: This should work, but it's unreliable.  Date.parse('2020-06-06') should return the same timestamp as Date.parse('June 6, 2020'), but it doesn't.  (1591401600000 vs 1591423200000)

Comment: php's strtotime and javascripts Date.parse are only similar at a basic level. As Ivan has commented above, strtotime is able to do far more by guessing the format and taking relative dates like 'tomorrow'.

Comment: I've updated the answer to remove the suggestion that this is somehow equivalent to `strtotime()`. There is no comparable functionality without an external library, which is why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17606427/1255289) got my +1.

Answer (score 44):

Check out [this](http://locutus.io/php/datetime/strtotime/) implementation of PHP's strtotime() in JavaScript!

I found that it works identically to PHP for everything that I threw at it.

> Update: this function as per version 1.0.2 can't handle this case: `'2007:07:20 20:52:45'`
> (Note the `:` separator for year and month)

## Update 2018:

This is now available as an [`npm` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/locutus)! Simply `npm install locutus` and then in your source:

```
var strtotime = require('locutus/php/datetime/strtotime');
```

Comment: I don't normally like answers that are just links to libraries, but in this case since JavaScript doesn't handle nearly the crazy cases as strtotime so this is a fantastic answer.

Thank you!

Comment: Latest release of Locutus (7 Sep 2018 at this time) does not handle strings like 'yesterday 19:00'.

Answer (score 5):

I jealous the strtotime() in php, but I do mine in javascript using moment. Not as sweet as that from php, but does the trick neatly too.

```
// first day of the month
var firstDayThisMonth = moment(firstDayThisMonth).startOf('month').toDate();
```

Go back and forth using the `subtract()` and `add()` with the `endOf()` and `startOf()`:

```
// last day of previous month
var yesterMonthLastDay = moment(yesterMonthLastDay).subtract(1,'months').endOf('month').toDate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Browser support for parsing strings [is inconsistent](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.

Try [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) - it provides cross-browser functionality for [parsing dates](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

```
var timestamp = moment("2013-02-08 09:30:26.123");
console.log(timestamp.milliseconds()); // return timestamp in milliseconds
console.log(timestamp.second()); // return timestamp in seconds
```

Comment: This does not fully answer the question (and has a negative score).  Is there a way to revoke the bounty?

Answer (score 0):

There are few modules that provides similar behavior, but not exactly like PHP's strtotime. Among few alternatives I found [date-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-util)  yields the best results.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var strdate = new Date('Tue Feb 07 2017 12:51:48 GMT+0200 (Türkiye Standart Saati)');
var date = moment(strdate).format('DD.MM.YYYY');
$("#result").text(date); //07.02.2017
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: *Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js `Date()`* – sooo… same as `new Date(strdate)` really…

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can exploit a sample function like :

```js
function strtotime(date, addTime){
  let generatedTime=date.getTime();
  if(addTime.seconds) generatedTime+=1000*addTime.seconds; //check for additional seconds 
  if(addTime.minutes) generatedTime+=1000*60*addTime.minutes;//check for additional minutes 
  if(addTime.hours) generatedTime+=1000*60*60*addTime.hours;//check for additional hours 
  return new Date(generatedTime);
}

let futureDate = strtotime(new Date(), {
    hours: 1, //Adding one hour
    minutes: 45 //Adding fourty five minutes
  });
document.body.innerHTML = futureDate;
```

`

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to convert the datetime to unix timestamp, you can do this using the `Moment` Library.

For Vue.js, you can do something like

```
let start = "2022/02/02 02:02:02";
return moment(start).format("x");
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript itself does not have a function like PHP's `strtotime()` to convert natural (English) language to a `Date` object.

Therefore you need a library (or write something yourself).
A library that is currently (2023) well maintained is Chrono: https://github.com/wanasit/chrono

I supports strings like "10 days after next Friday". A bonus of Chrono is that it also supports some other languages.