# create JavaScript Date object from date string

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a valid JavaScript Date object from the following string "010-10-25T23:25:55.847Z".

This string comes out of a PostGIS database "timestamp with time zone" Data Type field.

Anyone know how i can do this?

Fail:
**Edit:**Sorry, i had bad date string:

```
var startDate = new Date("2010-10-30T14:10:42.377Z");
```

**EDIT #2: This works fine now with the RIGHT date string.... sorry.**

```
var startDate = new Date("2010-10-30T14:10:42.377Z");
```

Comment: What is that date? Oct 25th 1910?

Comment: @Joey: sorry i had bad date string please see edit. 2010-10-30T14:10:42.377Z

Comment: The answer you accepted gives you the complete wrong answer. It could be confusing for people searching this in the future.

Comment: @Joey: how is it wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/gU77h/ It looks right to me.

Comment: not **your** solution, but Mark Davies is wrong, which you marked as correct. Yours is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links might help:

[Javascript equivalent of php's strtotime()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048204/javascript-equiv-of-php-strtotime-urgent)

http://phpjs.org/functions/strtotime:554

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what that format it, but this will give you each number:

```
var results = "010-10-25T23:25:55.847Z".match(/\d+\.{0,1}\d+/g);
var year = results[0]; // maybe ?
var month = results[1];
var day = results[2];
var etc...;
new Date(year, --month, day, hour, minutes, seconds);
```

or if it's kinda like UTC,

```
new Date(Date.UTC.apply(this, "010-10-25T23:25:55.847Z".match(/\d+\.{0,1}\d+/g)))
```