# Validate the date format withou using regular expression

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a javascript date format validation without using regular expression. When I entered the date 26/02/2013 I am having an alert value of Wed Sep 2 2093 and the error message  the date is not a valid format

Any help will be appreciate

```
    function CheckDateFormat(StartDateform)     

    {   
            var StartDateform= document.getElementById('tblTarget').rows[1].cells[StartDate].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;        
            spl = StartDateform.split("/"); 


            var testDate=new Date(spl[2],spl[0]-1,spl[1]);              

            year= testDate.getFullYear();                   
            month = testDate.getMonth()+1;                  
            day= testDate.getDate();

            alert ("the date value is "+ " "+ testDate);

        if (day!==spl[1] || month!==spl[0] || year!==spl[2])                    
        {
            alert ("the date value is "+ " "+ testDate);
            alert(StartDateform + " " + "Is an Invalid Date. Please use the format 'MM/DD/YYYY'");
            return false;
        }


        return true;                        
    }                   

    function Submit() 
    {
        if(CheckDateFormat())
        {
        $('button_submit').click(); 
        alert('New rate submitted');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why without a regular expression? Regular expressions are great for this kind of thing.

Comment: Just for your information, there exist some really mature JS libraries which do a great job on parsing dates, like **http://momentjs.com/**.

Comment: @rjmunro regexp is bad for validating dates, because you will need to validate a lot of invalid dates as well, f.ex leap years and other irregularities in the calendar.

Comment: why are you passing `StartDateform` as Parameter whereas you have not use that and not passed when calling function..

Comment: Just parse it...! and cross fingers

Comment: A previous post might prove to be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042042/create-javascript-date-object-from-date-string

Comment: 26/02/2013 is not a valid MM/DD/YYYY format, your code is working.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) expects Y/M/D:

> `Date` - Creates JavaScript Date instances which let you work with
>   dates and times.
>
> Syntax
>
> `new Date();`
>   `new Date(value);`
>   `new Date(dateString);`
>   **`new Date(year, month, day [hour, minute, second, millisecond]);`**

If the date is `26/02/2013`, you're feeding it with Y/D-1/M:

```
new Date(spl[2],spl[0]-1,spl[1]);
```

Substracting 1 from the day doesn't make any sense so I guess you've just messed the indexes.