# Extract date from string - react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Currently, I am working on receipt scanning app. I need a date from an extracted text:

[image]

So the date format is fixed. So how can I use regx to extract date?

Comment: will the date always have `dd/mm/yy` format ?

Comment: @Dane yes it will

Comment: Googling `javascript extract date from string` has *loads* of results

Comment: [How to extract date from string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060186/how-to-extract-date-from-string-using-javascript)

Comment: [javascript extract date via regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478426/javascript-extract-date-via-regular-expression)

Comment: [Javascript: Extract a date from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550416/javascript-extract-a-date-from-a-string)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple RegEx to capture the dates in this format would be

```
/\s\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\s/
```

and then use `String.prototype.trim()` to trim away leading and trailing whitespaces.

Using:

```
/\s[0123]\d\/[01]\d\/\d\d\s/
```

provides a little more validation, removing invalid months and days.