# How to check if todays date is same as a given date in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to check if today's date is = 04/01/2013 in a PHP file.
I have written the following JS Script. 
But I am getting some error. Dont know why.
Please help

```
//This function will return if today is the date that we are looking for
function isToday($time) // midnight second
{
    alert('1');
    return (strtotime($time) === strtotime('today'));
 }
```

Testing using the following:

```
if (isToday('2013-04-01 00:00:00.0') )
{
  alert('Yes true');
}
else
{
  alert("No false');
}
```

Please help how to compare today date = 04/01/2013. Thanks.

Comment: Are you coding in JavaScript, or PHP ? I'm confused. What's the error you're getting ? strtotime is a PHP function, where the rest is JavaScript it looks like.

Comment: are you trying to use `strtotime` in javascript?

Comment: My page is a PHP page but yes, I am checking this in JS.

Comment: JS can't call PHP functions like that.

Comment: @kevingreen - So how do I check this in JS?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do a date/time compare in JavaScript, you will be best off checking this question asked previously:

[Javascript equivalent of php's strtotime()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048204/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-strtotime)

That is a strtotime equivalent in JavaScript.

Here's a brief example:

```
var d = new Date("2013-04-01");
if(d == new Date()) {
    alert('yes')
} else {
    alert('no')
}
```

Comment: This might have an issue that it's to the second I think.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP:

```
// Get the time
$serverDate = date('d/m/Y',time());

// Date to check against
$dateToCheck = '04/01/2013';

if($dateToCheck == $serverDate) {
  alert('Yes true');
} else {
  alert('No false');
}
```

Comment: How to find out the server Hour diff?

Comment: Edited answer - Look at the first line

Comment: If I dont need to worry about timezone and it is presumed that the server is in Eastern Timezone?