# How to convert a string to a javascript date object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im want to convert a UTC date and time string to the current time for the x axis on a chart. I'm pretty sure I'm not using Date.parse correctly. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/chart/ajax_get_chart", // the URL of the controller action method
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        var result = JSON.parse(result);
        series = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          date = Date.parse(result[i]['date']); 
          tempArray = [parseFloat(result[i]['price'])];
          series.push(tempArray);
          series.push(date);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of `result[i]['date']` and is there any error message?

Comment: You are not assigning the `parse()` result to anything.

Comment: @acdcjunior I figured that was the problem, but I can't seem to get the right syntax to assign it, I'm new to javascript

Comment: What do you want to do, really? To assign it to a variable is simple, but we need to know what is it you really need to guide you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm guessing this has never been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048204/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-strtotime

Comment: You could put them in the same array: `tempArray = [Date.parse(result[i]['date']), parseFloat(result[i]['price'])];`

Comment: @acdcjunior I have a chart of bitcoin prices that updates live every time you refresh the page.  Im getting the correct UTC in my console, but on the x axis of the chart it comes up as every other day in the month of January.  I want the x-axis to have the current time up to the second.

Answer (score 9):

```
Date.parse(result[i]['date']);
```

You just parsed the date into a return value, then completely ignored the result.

You need to do something with the return value.

Also, `Date.parse()` returns a UNIX timestamp.
To create a `Date` instance, call `new Date(str)`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what to do with the return value, I'm new to javascript.

Comment: Just to make it a bit clearer: `x = Date.parse( datestring )` will parse a string as "Sun June 7 2013 10:00:00" or any other format to a UNIX timestamp (int) and asign it to x. `x = new Date( datestring )` will call the constructor with above string and assign a javascript Date object to x. You can use the Date functions, like `x.getTime()` to return the timestamp you would get with `parse` too or for example `x.getDate()` to get the day of the month.

Comment: @evann: What don't you understand? You probably want to put it in the array.