# Why returns zero strtotime with a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php

In this case works:

```
$var = "05/20/2016 12:00";
echo gettype ($var);
$ini = strtotime($var)*1000;
```

But when I use javascript variable and although both are format string it returns zero. Why?

```
$var = "<script>document.write(date)</script>";
echo gettype ($var);
$ini = strtotime($var)*1000;
```

Comment: read it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048204/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-strtotime

Answer (score 1):

PHP is being compiled first on the server, you are assuming that

```
$var = "<script>document.write(date)</script>";
```

is resolving to something like `$var = "05/20/2016 12:00";` but it isn't because the javascript compiling doesn't kick in until the output has reached the client.

You're passing the literal string `"<script>document.write(date)</script>"` to PHP's `strtotime()` function, hence returning a zero.

If you `echo $var` prior to `echo gettype($var)` you'll see exactly what is being passed to strtotime.

`var_dump()` is even better for debugging the current value of a variable.

```
$var = "<script>document.write(date)</script>";
var_dump($var)
echo gettype ($var);
$ini = strtotime($var)*1000;
```

Comment: The problem with both `echo` and `var_dump` here is that they will dump a valid HTML script tag to the browser, which will show as nothing (except maybe an error because `date` is undefined)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Maybe something like `echo htmlspecialchars($var);`?

Comment: The beatuty of `var_dump` is that it tells you the **length** of the variable too, so if it looks blank but says the string is 44 characters long you know that something is being hidden. Also, using the browsers 'view_source' will expose the true raw string.