# Convert text to date object

Tags: javascript, php, string-conversion

What i want is the possibility to convert the string "5 minutes ago", or the string "10 hours ago" to a javascript date object in an easy manner.

Date.parse expects a date string and i believe that function does not meet my requirements.

In PHP i can do something like this:

*Code*

```
$string = "5 minutes ago";
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$d = strtotime($now . " + " . str_replace("ago","",$string));
echo "Current time: " . $now;
echo "<br>";
echo "Altered time: " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$d);
```

*Output*

```
Current time: 2016-12-03 20:56:33
Altered time: 2016-12-03 21:01:33
```

and

How can i convert the string "5 minutes ago" or "10 hours ago" into a javascript date object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript equivalent of php's strtotime()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048204/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-strtotime)

Comment: Seems like an X/Y problem, you probably have something that outputs those strings and does the conversion, there's rarely any need to reverse engineer that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to recognize that you have something in the form "X units ago", convert units to milliseconds, multiply by X (after converting X from a string to a number), and subtract that number of milliseconds from the current time before you convert the current time to a string.

```
then = new Date((new Date())-60000)
```

will make `then` be 60 seconds ago

If s is the string "5 minutes ago" then

```
var m = s.match(/(\d+) ((minutes)|(seconds)|(hours)) ago/)
```

should give you `m` as an array such that `m[1]` is a string that sequence of one or more digits, in this case `"5"` and `m[2]` will be one of the strings "minutes", "seconds", or "hours".