# How to convert html5 input time to a timestamp in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have `2:12 PM` as my time from an input, and I want to convert it to a timestamp combined with the current date.

I can get the current timestamp using `Date.now()` but my problem is I want the time to be based on the input.

If moment can be used, then better. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: And you're not capable to read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9151985/7479709).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass in the time format to moment's [constructor](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), along with the input's value as string to parse it into a moment object. Like this:

```js
console.log(moment('2:12 PM',"hh:mm a").format('lll'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use momentJS custom parsing:

```
moment("2:12 PM", "H:mm A");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Using simple JavaScript

1. Take date

   ```
   var d = new Date();
   ```
2. Split it

   ```
   var l = d.toString().split(":");
   ```
3. Slice it

   ```
   var f =l[0].slice(0,-2);
   ```
4. Get your time variable

   ```
   var ty="11:22:00";
   ```
5. Create Date

   ```
   var j = new Date(f + ty);
   ```

**Done, It's in `j`**

---

**One line solution:**

```
var d = new Date();
var ty = "11:22:00";
var newDate = new Date(d.toString().split(":")[0].slice(0,-2) + ty);
```

It's the full date, you can use and change it as you like.