# Regular expression for date

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a date format like: **YYYY-MM-DD**, as we all know that the months only contains numbers like *01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12*. How can I actually write a regular expression that allows me to only get the correct months as well as dates. I could only do something like this...

```
var date = /[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}/;

    function checkDate(Date)
    {
        if (date.test(Date))
        {
        alert("Valid Date");
        }
            else
            {
                    alert("Invalid Date");
            }

    }
```

Thus, if the date is for example, **2008-24-43**. It will still return me valid date.

Thanks.

Comment: I really wouldn't use `Date` as an argument name. You'll shadow the `Date` constructor function. (In general, the JavaScript convention is to use camelCase or underscoring for argument names [e.g., "date" rather than "Date", and "niftyThing" or "nifty_thing" rather than "NiftyThing"], not initial caps. Initial caps is pretty much reserved -- again, only by convention -- for constructor functions. Unless you're Microsoft.)

Answer (score 6):

Parsing dates with regular expressions could be a challenging task. I would recommend you taking a look at [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

the following regular expression matches a date in yyyy-mm-dd format from between 1900-01-01 and 2099-12-31, with a choice of four separators: - / . and white space.

```
/^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/
```

source: www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest not going that path using regular expressions. You'll run into more problems than needed. Rather, read for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-date-string-in-javascript) to see what people have tried before.

You should use `new Date()` to check if inputted date is really valid. Don't reinvent the wheel.

For your example, you can use this:

```
var strDate = "2008-07-23";
var dateParts = strDate.split("-");

var date = new Date(dateParts[0], (dateParts[1] - 1) ,dateParts[2]);
```

Disclaimer: idea taken from linked page.

If a date is not valid, you can use strategies from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you basic checking:

```
^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

but it will still allow things like 2001-02-29.  You may be best doing a two-stage process - first do the regex for speed, then use DateTime.Parse:

```
try
{
    DateTime.Parse(Date);
    alert("Valid Date");
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    alert("Invalid Date");
}
```