# Count Number of days between 2 dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me get the number of days between today's date and some other date.. Here is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vQnHz/)

It gives me `NaN`

Here is what I came up with. My [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vQnHz/3/)

```
var cellvalue="2011-08-18 11:49:01.0 IST";
var firstDate = new Date();
var secondDate = cellvalue.substring(0, cellvalue.length-4);

alert(diffOf2Dates(firstDate,secondDate));

function diffOf2Dates(todaysDate,configDate)
{
/*var udate="2011-08-18 11:49:01.0";
var configDate=new Date(udate);*/

var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = todaysDate; // Todays date
var secondDate = new Date(configDate);

var diffDays = Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay));
console.info(firstDate+", "+secondDate);
//console.info(Math.ceil(diffDays));

return Math.ceil(diffDays);
}
```

Comment: try using new Date("Aug 19 2011");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
var firstDate = new Date(); // Todays date
var secondDate = new Date(2011,08,19, 11,49,01);

var diffDays = (firstDate.getDate() - secondDate.getDate());
```

It was showing NAN as your constructor is wrong. check yourself by alerting secondDate in your original code

Edit : above code will work if both dates are in same month, for general case

```
var oneDay  = 24*60*60*1000;
var diffDays = Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / oneDay);
```

Also this will give result as fraction of date, so if you want to count whole dates you can use Math.ceil or Math.floor

Comment: @Pradeep: [This Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vQnHz/5/) does not work in IE, but works in all other browsers can you take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
var udate="2011-08-19 11:49:01.0 GMT+0530";
```

The IST part is not valid

Comment: Chrome seems to accept the ISO date format but most other browsers don't. So this solution isn't cross-browser.

Answer (score 3):

your input date is incorrect that is why it is failing. anyways here is some code that should help you with it.

```
var DateDiff = {

    inDays: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000));
    },

    inWeeks: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000*7));
    },

    inMonths: function(d1, d2) {
        var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
        var d2Y = d2.getFullYear();
        var d1M = d1.getMonth();
        var d2M = d2.getMonth();

        return (d2M+12*d2Y)-(d1M+12*d1Y);
    },

    inYears: function(d1, d2) {
        return d2.getFullYear()-d1.getFullYear();
    }
}
var udate="2011-08-05 11:49:01";
var configDate=new Date(udate);

var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date(); // Todays date
var secondDate = new Date(udate);

alert(secondDate);

var diffDays = DateDiff .inDays(firstDate,secondDate);

alert(diffDays );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also [this Example of mine](http://jsfiddle.net/vQnHz/5/) does not work in IE, but works in all other browsers can you take a look. Thanks

Comment: You can answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120485/continuation-of-count-difference-between-two-numbers)

Comment: the problem is the fomat of the date: ie doesnt support the way other browsers do.. run this: http://jsfiddle.net/vQnHz/7/

Answer (score 2):

if you have `udate` format like `28-07-2011` you can use this

```
var checkindatestr = "28-07-2011";
var dateParts = checkindatestr.split("-");

var checkindate = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0]);
var now = new Date();
var difference = now - checkindate;
var days = difference / (1000*60*60*24);

alert(days);
```

[how to compare two dates in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762945/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the difference correctly but the problem is that `secondDate` is an invalid date. `Date` cannot work with that date format, it needs `"August 08, 2011 11:49:01"` as input - and if your date has a different format then you have to convert it. Note that `Date` has only rudimentary timezone recognition, you can only be sure that "UTC" or "GMT" will be recognized correctly - you shouldn't use other time zones.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `udate` variable value. The date format is not correct. Try initializing the date in this format:

```
var secondDate = new Date(year,month,date);
```