# Cant assign value from getElementById to date?

Tags: javascript

I've got this:

```
    var lDate = document.getElementById('txtLeaveDate');
    var rDate = document.getElementById('txtReturnedDate');
```

Err...javascript so how do I assign the value of txtLeaveDate to a date variable

I tried:

`var myDate = new Date(lDate.value);`

But this assigns some long value....

I can do it if I try:

```
var today = new Date();
  var day2 = new Date();
  day2.setDate(today.getDate() + 30);
```

But the issue is I need to get the date from txtLeaveDate not by a date variable

## edit complete code

```
var theLDate = new Date(lDate.value);
        var theRDate = new Date(rDate.value);

        //check if return date is a sunday, if it is no need
        //to do anything,
        //else make it a sunday
        while (theRDate.getDay() != 0) 
            theRDate.setDate(theRDate.getDate() + 1);

        //at this point RDate is a sunday...
        while(theLDate.valueOf() <= theRDate.valueOf())
            {
                if(theLDate.getDay() == 0)
                    {   //sunday
                        var li = document.createElement('li');
                        li.setAttribute('id', ['liID' + count]);
                        var month = theLDate.getMonth();
                        var day = theLDate.getDate();
                        var year = theLDate.getFullYear();
                        var theDay = month + '/' + day + '/' + year + ' (Sunday)';
                        li.innerHTML = theDay;
                        ul.appendChild(li);
                    }   
                theLDate.setDate(theLDate.getDate() + 1);
                count++;
            }
```

But when I pick 2 dates in my calendar like so:

[image]

Comment: What's the value of `lDate.value`?

Comment: @Felix it does show a date like 7/10/2011 but if I do `alert(lDate.value.getDate())` it says this method is not available.

Comment: var myDate = new Date(lDate.value); is correct. Perhaps your date is not in a readable format.

Comment: Take a look a this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-date-string-in-javascript

Comment: @diodeus - if I try that and say alert(theLDate.valueOf()); it returns 1309924800000...Im gonna post all my code, and when it adds li items if i select july it adds items for june...

Comment: .value is for form fields. If this is not a form field, use .innerHTML

Comment: @Diodeus - see my post edit with complete image details I hope this makes sense

Comment: Go get this tool. It will help: http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I try that and say `alert(theLDate.valueOf());` it returns
>   `1309924800000`

That's because that *is* the value of a Date object, measured in milliseconds since 1/1/1970 00:00:00, in this case corresponding to Wed Jul  6 04:00:00 2011 UTC.

Try using `.toString()` instead and you'll see the corresponding date in a human readable format.

The problem with your dates appearing to be in June is because the `getMonth()` function for odd reasons returns the month [**zero based**, i.e. January == 0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth).

Comment: This looks like the correct answer to me.  In addition, this line of code should be changed from this" `li.setAttribute('id', ['liID' + count]);` to this `li.setAttribute('id', 'liID' + count);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.innerHTML`, otherwise you are not returning the text in the element.

```
var lDate = document.getElementById('txtLeaveDate').innerHTML;
var myDate = new Date(lDate);
document.write(myDate);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ua85k/

Answer (score 0):

Months returned by the someDate.getMonth method are zero-indexed (from 0 to 11).  So if using them to create a string add 1!

```
var month = theLDate.getMonth() + 1;
```