# how to validate a field for DOB using forward slashes dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a string is a legal “dd/mm/yyyy” date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582828/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-legal-dd-mm-yyyy-date)

I have a a regular text field that I want to validate that im using for date of birth.

it's like dd/mm/yyyy. Im wondering how i can check that the user entered the date in the correct format with the slashes. I have a php script to calculate the age from the entered data and strips the slashes in order to do so. I figure i'd run with that, but just in case a user enters it wrong, well lol, you know how that is...

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582828/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-legal-dd-mm-yyyy-date

Comment: in php, sorry i didnt put that in there

Comment: You definitely need to use jquery to do this

Comment: thats cool, whatever will get the job done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!preg_match('#^(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})$#', $date, $matches)) {
    die('Invalid format');
}

$dob = mktime(0, 0, 0, $matches[2], $matches[1], $matches[3]);

if (date('d/m/Y', $dob) != $date) {
    die('Invalid date');
}

echo 'User was born on ' . date('l, F jS, Y', $dob);
```

Comment: cool! now, one question so I can give this a go, how would I plug this  to the field? Would I do a do_action or something else? Im working in wordpress, I should've noted that also

Comment: I don't know how you can integrate this into your project, since I don't know its structure. You should probably open a new question for that.

Comment: well I definitely think this is on the right track, I just need to direct it to the text input field. But if I take a look at the way wordpress validates normal fields, I can pretty much tie this to it I believe. Thanks again