# Jquery DOB inputs fields to be validated

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, validation

to accept only numbers up to 31 (no 32, no 62, etc).

Currently works perfectly but if I type 50/80/1977 works anyway.

I need to validate the inputs DD MM YYYY. Any suggestion?

I don't want to use datapicker. and the number have to be in a UK format. DD/MM/YYYY.

the E.G. http://jsfiddle.net/davidesitua/bhdry/49/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this function as an answer to another question, but I think it should do what you want -

```
function isValidDate(strDate) {
    if (strDate.length != 10) return false;
    var dateParts = strDate.split("/");
    var date = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);
    if (date.getDate() == dateParts[0] && date.getMonth() == (dateParts[1] - 1) && date.getFullYear() == dateParts[2]) {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/2r6eX/2/

To use with your code, you could do something like -

```
if (!isValidDate(enteredDOB)) {
    $("#invalidDOB").fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
}
```

Demo of code integrated with your code - http://jsfiddle.net/ScEuV/1/

Further solutions are given in the original question - [How to check if a string is a legal "dd/mm/yyyy" date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582828/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-legal-dd-mm-yyyy-date/)

Comment: thanks, but I'm quite confused, could you update the code on  http://jsfiddle.net/davidesitua/bhdry/49/ please?

Comment: Just a note: I tried to provide future date and it says that I'm young but i doesn't even exist yet (if to believe to the date provided).