# Javascript parseInt() with leading zeros

Tags: javascript

Javascript's parseInt function does not seem to completely work.

```
parseInt("01") returns 1
parseInt("02") returns 2
parseInt("03") returns 3
parseInt("04") returns 4
parseInt("05") returns 5
parseInt("06") returns 6
parseInt("07") returns 7
parseInt("08") returns 0
parseInt("09") returns 0
```

You can't explain that. [Give it a try. (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/UdbNd/)

**Edit** Since this question was asked and answered, the "feature" of defaulting to octal radix has been deprecated. [[1](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)] [[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)]

Comment: `You can't explain that.`  Yes you can => https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: are you sure??????????? it should not be like this

Comment: This is just funny ... Just a little bit ago the same question was posted, but a different user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763362/why-does-parseint09-return-0-but-parseint07-return-7

Comment: Since ages, any number starting with 0 represents OCTAL and 0x represents Hexa-Decimal. I believe this is universal for all languages, but again I may be wrong.

Comment: FYI: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), is better online JavaScript tester than http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp.

Comment: @JohnHartsock Yeh, it's because we were both on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761997/difference-between-datetimes/8763241#8763241

Comment: Thank you for the update. I was confused as to why this was giving me different values in FF and Chrome: alert(parseInt('0123')). Chrome outputs 123, and FF outputs 83. They seem to have different default values for the radix parameter when there's a leading 0.

Comment: as of 2015 this behavior (default to octal) is not present in standard modern browsers on Windows.
I only managed to reproduce it on Safari 5.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

This is because if a number starts with a '0', it's treated as base 8 (octal).

You can force the base by passing the base as the 2nd parameter.

```
parseInt("09", 10) // 9
```

According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), the 2nd parameter is optional, but it's *not always* assumed to be 10, as you can see from your example.

Comment: yeah, but if it's assumed octal, it should be returning 11 for 09 instead of 0.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha: Other way around.  `11` in base 8 is `9` in base 10.  `09` is not a valid base 8 number.

Comment: But I want 09 after parseInt, is there any way around

Answer (score 44):

Calls to `parseInt` should always specify a base in the second argument:

```
parseInt("08", 10);
```

Earlier versions of JavaScript treat strings starting with `0` as octal (when no base is specified) and neither `08` nor `09` are valid octal numbers.

From the Mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If radix is undefined or 0, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> - If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16
>     (hexadecimal).
> - If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight
>     (octal). This feature is non-standard, and some implementations
>     deliberately do not support it (instead using the radix 10).  For this
>     reason **always specify a radix when using parseInt**.
> - If the input string
>     begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).
>
> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt returns NaN.

And from the [ECMAScript 3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) standard:

> When radix is 0 or **undefined** and the string's number begins with a **0**
>   digit not followed by an **x** or **X**, then the implementation may, at its
>   discretion, interpret the number either as being octal or as being
>   decimal. Implementations are encouraged to interpret numbers in this
>   case as being decimal.

The latest version of JavaScript ([ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)) [abandons this behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#ECMAScript_5_Removes_Octal_Interpretation), but you should *still specify the radix* to satisfy older browsers.

Comment: Since this is deprecated, in the future you would be fine with using leading zeros isn't it?

Answer (score 16):

There is a Radix parameter

```
parseInt(value, base)
```

Where base is the radix.

In this case you are evaluating base10 (decimal) numbers,
therefore use

```
parseInt(value, 10);
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't seem to be completely valid in new browsers. Internet Explorer 9 and 10 will return 8 if you execute 'parseInt("08")' whereas Internet Explorer 8 and previous versions will return 0 (IE10 in quirks mode will also return 0).

The latest version of Chrome also returns 8 so they must have changed the interpretation recently.

Comment: Yep, the behavior has changed. I'll update my answer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#ECMAScript_5_Removes_Octal_Interpretation

Comment: Yes, Firefox and Chrome latest version doesn't have a problem now.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is deprecated now. But you can still use radix in `parseInt` to convert number of other bases into base-10. E.g.,

```
var baseTwoNumber = parseInt('0010001', 2);
```

returns `17` (which is base-10 of `0010001`).

Answer (score 0):

Tip: As you now know when default to octal has been deprecated. Here is how you would fix it in legacy browsers

```
// ES-5 15.1.2.2
if (parseInt('08') !== 8 || parseInt('0x16') !== 22) {
    parseInt = (function (origParseInt) {
        var hexRegex = /^0[xX]/;
        return function parseIntES5(str, radix) {
            str = String(str).trim();
            if (!Number(radix)) {
                radix = hexRegex.test(str) ? 16 : 10;
            }
            return origParseInt(str, radix);
        };
    }(parseInt));
}
```

Comment: P.S.: if you use just a constant number with a leading zero (instead of a string), it is still treated as base 8 in all current browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have changed now in most browsers.

Firefox 51.0.1 (64-bit)

```
parseInt("09")   // 9
```

Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

```
parseInt("09")   // 9
```

Safari 10.0 (12602.1.50.0.10)

```
parseInt("09")   // 9
```

=====

### Recommended Practice

Having said that, just to be on the safer side and to avoid issues, use the base/radix parameter as suggested in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8763427/2369867).

```
parseInt("09", 10)    // 9
```

### Extra test

I just wanted to test this as well, if the argument is not a string.
Chrome & Safari gives exact result. Firefox too returns proper result, but with a warning.

```
parseInt(09)     // 9. (Warning: SyntaxError: 09 is not a legal ECMA-262 octal constant)
```

Comment: If the value starts with 0 and is a number, parseInt will still use base 8. Try parseInt(020)

Comment: Yes. I have even pointed to the suggested answer. And I know best practices and bad features to avoid. So I have given **Recommended practice** as well in my answer.