# get all numbers in a string and push to an array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, numbers

So if I had the following string:

```
'(01) Kyle Hall - Osc (04) Cygnus - Artereole (07) Forgemasters - Metalic (10) The Todd Terry Project - Back to the Beat (14) Broken Glass - Style of the Street'
```

I could look through the string and push any numbers in the string to an array, which would look like this:

```
[01,04,07,10,14]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a regular expression:

```
var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g);
```

This will result in `["01", "04", "07", "10", "14"]` (array of strings). If the type of the elements matters to you you can follow up with `.map(Number)` to convert to numbers:

```
var reallyNumbers = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
```

which will result in `[1, 4, 7, 10, 14]`.

Note that [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is not available in IE earlier than version 9, so depending on your compat requirements you might need a polyfill. There's a ready-made one on MDN.

Comment: I think he wants numbers in the output array.

Comment: @DaniloValente: It shouldn't make a difference in almost all cases. But I expanded the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = '(01) Kyle Hall - Osc (04) Cygnus - Artereole (07) Forgemasters - Metalic (10) The Todd Terry Project - Back to the Beat (14) Broken Glass - Style of the Street';
var nums = str.match(/\d+/g);
nums.map(function (num) {
    return parseInt(num, 10);
});
```

For browsers that does not support `Array.prototype.map`, use this code:

```
var str = '(01) Kyle Hall - Osc (04) Cygnus - Artereole (07) Forgemasters - Metalic (10) The Todd Terry Project - Back to the Beat (14) Broken Glass - Style of the Street';
var nums = str.match(/\d+/g);
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str[i] = parseInt(str[i], 10);
}
```

Comment: Note that [you should always specify the radix with `parseInt`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763396/javascript-parseint-with-leading-zeros). As it stands this code should be considered buggy.