# Java ParseInt() - Catching Strings with a leading zero

Tags: java, zero, parseint, leading-zero

Java's [ParseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) method will happily parse decimal values supplied with a leading zero without throwing an exception, stripping the zero:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt("050", 10);
```

will result in the integer value 50.

But, I have an application requiring a string such as this to be rejected as invalid input. My solution to the problem so far has been to convert the parsed integer back to a string, and compare the lengths of original/parsed strings to see if any character has been stripped, eg:

```
String original = "050";
value  = Integer.parseInt( "050", 10);
String parsed = Integer.toString(value);
if (original.length() != parsed.length()) {
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Which works fine, but feels a little hacky. Are there better ways of detecting and handling a leading zero?

Comment: Can't you use regex to check for leading 0`s`?

Comment: Does it have to account for more than one leading 0? e.g. `0050`. Furthermore, what about leading spaces or anything like that?

Comment: Leading spaces are allowed in my case, but one or more leading zeroes `0050` should be caught

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript parseInt() with leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763396/javascript-parseint-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: @ShawnBush this is a substantially different question as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ChrisSprague thanks, I did read around before posting (It's my first question ever...) and the Javascript questions tend to regard the default radix of base-8 causing weird behaviour with leading zeroes. Java defaults to decimal anyway.

Comment: @s-low Right. I was addressing another commenter who flagged this as a duplicate question. Your question is about a `parseInt` issue in Java where the other one is a different issue, and it's in Javascript... (so the duplicate reported is incorrect.)

Comment: @ChrisSprague understood - I was just saying thanks

Comment: @s-low ah. no problem then (:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check if the first character is 0 :

```
if (original.charAt(0)=='0')
```

or

```
if (original.startsWith("0"))
```

If the String starts with a 0, you don't want to call `parseInt` at all.

I think that comparing a single character is more efficient than using regular expressions.

Comment: this should be the answer, regex is to heavy.

Comment: So simple. Thanks for this - I'm new to Java and only just beginning to realise that things like `startsWith` actually exist...

Comment: But this wont catch the leading whitespace beeing noticed in a comment anymore, and should be trimmed.

Answer (score 2):

you could work with regex and check if it has a leading 0

you could just write

After seeing your comment about leading whitespaces beeing allowed you could use:

```
if(original.matches(".\\s0.*[1-9]")) // Wrong number with leading zeros
```

This way a 00000 would still be a zero, if it´s valid

Answer (score 0):

As you get a string input you can use the method `String.charAt(int)` to check for explicit characters.
However, when you are just using `input.charAt(0)` the user could avoid the leading zero with a space.

What I would suggest to do:

```
String decimalChars = "123456789";

boolean reject = true, hasZeros = false;
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input.charAt(i) == '0') { // or other chars you don't want
        hasZeros = true;
        reject = false;
    } else if (decimalChars.contains(input.charAt(i)) {
           if (hasZeros) {
               reject = true;
            } else {
                reject = false;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Using that you can do whatever you want to reject wrong inputs by checking `reject`. The code will break when it finds a character which is in the decimalChars array. `reject` will be true if it found a zero before, otherwise it'll be false. This code also allows spaces at the beginning and doesn't reject an input like `0000`. Empty strings will be rejected as well, because `reject` initializes with true.

I hope this helps!