# Firefox seem to parse int values wrong - whats wrong with my script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some sort of spaghetti code in a file. The file itself contains the input field for the Date of Birth (DOB).

The script work fine on Chrome and IE11, however it doesn't work on **Firefox**.

There's a bug where you need to pass a second parameter to `parseInt()`, but then I lose option validate the date. Therefore I need help to either cleanly parse numbers and put them together to a date-string.

I debugged it a little and found out that in FF there is no console log, whilst it clearly should do so. Basically, it seems that FF gets stuck somewhere, but I have no idea where and why.

Purpose of this script is to validate that the entered Values are either INT and combined verify the age of a customer (basically I want to check if he is 18 or not - based on 3 inputs, Day, Month, Year).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var customer_dob = new Varien.DOB('.customer-dob', <?php echo $this->isRequired() ? 'true' : 'false' ?>, '<?php echo $this->getDateFormat() ?>');
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
        var sPath = window.location.pathname;

        // OPTION 1: /customer/account/create/
        // OPTION 2: /onestepcheckout/
        // OPTION 3: /customer/account/edit/

        console.log(sPath);

        var age = [];

        if(sPath == "/onestepcheckout/"){
            var disButID = "#onestepcheckout-place-order";
        } else if (sPath == "/customer/account/create/") {
            var disButID = ".buttons-set button.button";
        } else if (sPath == "/customer/account/edit/") {
            var disButID = ".buttons-set button.button";
        }

        //console.log(disButID);

        //jQuery(disButID).prop("disabled", true);

        jQuery(".customer-dob input").each(function($){
            var entity = jQuery(this).attr("name");
            //console.log(entity);
            if(entity == "day" || entity == "month" || entity == "year"){
                var selector = jQuery(this).attr("data-selector");
                age[selector] = jQuery(this).val();
                getAge(age);
                //console.log("Change check: " + age);
            } else if (entity == "dob") {
                // ... 
            }
        });

        jQuery(".customer-dob input").change(function($){
            var selector = jQuery(this).attr("data-selector");
            age[selector] = jQuery(this).val();
            getAge(age);
            //console.log("Change check: " + age);
        });

        function getAge(age) {
            if(age["d"] && age["m"] && age["y"]){
                var day = age["d"];
                var month = age["m"];
                var year = age["y"];
                console.log("Date: " + day, month, year);

                unlockOrderButton(day, month, year);

            } else {
                // ... 
                //console.log(age.length);
            }
        }

        function unlockOrderButton(day, month, year){

            var dateString = parseInt(month) + "-" + parseInt(day) + "-" + parseInt(year);
            var today = new Date();
            var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
            var currentAge = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
            var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();

            if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
                currentAge--;
            } else {
                currentAge;
            }


            //var age = parseInt(curr);

            console.log(parseInt(currentAge));
            console.log("Unlock Button - Check");
            if(currentAge >= 18){
                jQuery(".customer-dob-error").removeClass("active");
                jQuery(disButID).prop("disabled", false);
                console.log("Unlock Button - Success. Age is: " + currentAge);
            } else {
                jQuery(".customer-dob-error").addClass("active");
                jQuery(disButID).prop("disabled", true);
                console.debug("Unlock Button - Fail. Age is: " + currentAge);
            }
        }
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="input-box customer-dob">
    <div class="dob-day">
             <input type="text" data-selector="d" id="billing:day" name="billing[day]" value="" title="Tag" class="input-text validate-custom">
             <label for="billing:day">TT</label>
         </div><div class="dob-month">
             <input type="text" data-selector="m" id="billing:month" name="billing[month]" value="" title="Monat" class="input-text validate-custom">
             <label for="billing:month">MM</label>
         </div><div class="dob-year">
             <input type="text" data-selector="y" id="billing:year" name="billing[year]" value="" title="Jahr" class="input-text validate-custom" autocomplete="off">
             <label for="billing:year">JJJJ</label>
         </div>    
    <div class="dob-full" style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" id="billing:dob" name="billing[dob]">
    </div>

    <div class="validation-advice" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

Firebug fails to show console's content, so I checked the built-in console.

```
Date: 17 02 1950  onestepcheckout:1073:5
Unlock Button - Check  onestepcheckout:1096:4
Unlock Button - Fail. Age is: NaN  onestepcheckout:1104:5
```

Comment: You mean nothing at all is logged to the console? Does `getAge` run? Add a breakpoint.

Comment: Nothing at all gets logged, yes. Not even `sPath` gets logged, so it seems that FF can't load jQuery which is my first guess, but wrong - since everything else works fine.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you don't need to `parseInt` the `currentAge` value. Also, the `else { currentAge; }` can be removed completely.

Comment: @Atr_Max: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: That's... weird. If you included jQuery, you should at least get `sPath` logged. If you didn't include jQuery properly, you should be getting errors about `jQuery` not existing. What if you add a `console.log(customer_dob)` directly after the `var customer_dob`?

Comment: Nothing at all. Maybe its a Firebug bug? Anyhow, it seems that jQuery triggers just fine, since jQuery is able to trigger `.customer-dob-error` as statet in the last `else` in my code.

Comment: Try with the built-in Firefox developer tools, sans Firebug.

Comment: Gotcha, Ryan. Here we have output. I gonna paste the content of it into the question.

Comment: can you post some html or a snippet?

Comment: use: `parseInt(value, 10)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript parseInt() with leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763396/javascript-parseint-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: Tried `parseInt(month, 10)` on function `unlockOrderButton`, but this seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are formatting your date string as `MM-DD-YYYY`. When
using a date string,
[`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)
expects a [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) formatted
date. Browsers often recognize other formats but support for them is not
uniform or consistent. Chrome recognizes `MM-DD-YYYY`, but Firefox does not. Go
to the console in Firefox and type in `new Date('01-01-2017')`, it will return
`Invalid Date`.  Calling `.getFullYear()` on an invalid date object returns
[`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)
subtracting `NaN` from the current year returns `NaN`. So, that is why
`currentAge` is `NaN` when your code runs in Firefox.

As of ES5, JavaScript now officially [supports the ISO-8601
format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#ECMAScript_5_ISO-8601_format_support)
for date strings, so if you switch your date string fromatting to `YYYY-MM-DD`,
it should work across all browsers.

```
var dateString = parseInt(year, 10) + "-" + parseInt(month, 10) + "-" + parseInt(day, 10);
```

Comment: Also, `age` [should be an object](https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/), not an array. `var age = {}`. In JS arrays are not associative arrays, are meant only for use with numeric indices. In JS objects are analogous to associative arrays, so use an object instead when using non-numeric property names. Arrays are themselves objects, which is why adding properties to them works, but it is not the way you should be doing it.