# How to Delete '000' before number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to delete multiple "0" when inputing in input html, necessarily, need use keypress, at the same time delete. For example when inputing 000000000 = 0, Instantly delete each symbol, or 000562 = 562. Thank's!

Comment: What have you tried, where is your attempt(s) and in what way doesn't it appear to be functioning as intended? You can't just write a "I want" list and have people write it for you. This isn't a free writing service.

Comment: You need to at least try to write some code and solve the problem first.

Comment: Please add the functions that you've already implemented with regard to this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript parseInt() with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763396/javascript-parseint-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: @AlonEitan - This has nothing to do with that other question.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this on keypress, because (even aside from the fact that users can edit input values without using the keyboard) trying to programmatically modify the value as they type means you have to maintain the current cursor position and so forth. Also if the user initially types "50000" by mistake and then tries to change the "5" to a "4" your auto-zero-removal behaviour would remove the zeros even though it shouldn't. Just remove the leading zeros on the change or blur event, easily done with the string `.replace()` function.

Comment: @nnnnnn But `parseInt('000562',10)` will give the same result as the user is asking for, or have I missed anything?

Comment: The parseInt() function may provide the result the OP wants, but for reasons completely unrelated to what that other question was asking about.

Comment: @nnnnnn I retracted my CV, but I still think that duplicate might have been helpful, since the OP shows zero efforts and research, and I couldn't find more accurate  question

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

HTML:

`<input type="text" id="myInput">`

JS:

```
var stripZeroesRegex = /^0+/;

function stripZeroes(str) {
    return str.replace(stripZeroesRegex, '0');
}


myInput.addEventListener('input', function(ev) {
    if (stripZeroesRegex.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = stripZeroes(this.value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OnKeyPress = "return onlyNumbers(this.id)"

function onlyNumbers(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode

    if (charCode == 48) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

when user press 0 then return false I don't know about how to remove but I know how to varify 0 pressed or not that's why I mention this method.