# ParseInt() strange octal behavior

Tags: javascript, parseint

I have to convert some input data to integer.
I found `parseInt()` function.
Everything is good if the input is string:

```js
console.log(parseInt("123")) //123
```

Even if the string starts with 0:

```js
console.log(parseInt("0123")) //123
```

But if a **number** starts with 0, it will give 83!

```js
    console.log(parseInt(0123)) //83 instead of 123
```

I heard about that's because octal behavior ([Javascript parseInt() with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763396/javascript-parseint-with-leading-zeros)), so I gave a radix parameter to it:

```js
    console.log(parseInt(0123,10)) //83!!!
```

**Still 83!!!**

And then, the strangest of all:
I thinked: octal 123 must give 123 in octal!
But it gave `NaN`:

```js
console.log(parseInt(0123, 8)) //NaN
```

Why this strange behavior?! And how can I fix it?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Behavior has nothing to do with `parseInt()`. Try `console.log(0123)`

Comment: `parseInt` expects a string. The answer to "how can I fix it?" is to pass the right kind of argument to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, you can defined a number (rather than a string) in octal format, then passed it to `parseInt`. Then `parseInt` casts that number to a string (`"83"`), and parses it again.

If you pass a string to `parseInt` you will get the expected result:

```js
console.log(parseInt('0123'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a combination of a string and a radix to get the correct value. Here's an example:

```
parseInt(01234) // returns 668
parseInt('01234', 10) // returns 1234
```

Comment: There is no information here that isn't already addressed in the existing answer.

Comment: My answer suggests using the radix as well as a string.

Comment: But the important part of the question is "why". OP has demonstrated they already know the correct way. You're parroting back to them what they already showed. That doesn't explain why the octal literal is handled differently.