# compare datetime currentdate javascript

Tags: javascript

I've txtStartDate control like that format : 09.03.2012

I want to compare txtStartDate value CurrentDate. if txtStartDate bigger than CurrentDate, i want to return true. how to to this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-date-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates in javascript suck. I recommend using this library FWIW, http://www.datejs.com/

Specifically http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#compare

and related

Also see

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parse for actually converting the text to a date object.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your dates: `20120309`, comparing is easy.

```
function chgDate(dte){
    var pm=new String(dte.getMonth()+1);if(pm.length<2) pm='0'+pm;
    var pd=new String(dte.getDate());if(pd.length<2) pd='0'+pd;
    var py=dte.getFullYear();
    return new Number(py+pm+pd);
}

function chgControl(dte){
    dte=dte.split('.');
    return new Number(dte[2]+dte[1]+dte[0]);
}

bool=(chgControl('09.03.2012')>chgDate(new Date()));
```

Comment: or just .getTime(), this still doesn't solve parsing the format into a date.

Comment: @j_mcnally Parsing the date now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a Date object from the text you have. This will probably involve taking the string and splitting it up and passing it to the `Date(year, month, day)` constructor. I can't tell which way round your days and months are though so I can't give you example code.

Once you've created a Date object you can compare it to the current date, which you can get using `new Date()`.