# how to check a date is within current week or current month or next month in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have some friends' birthdays and want to separate them as follows :

- birthdays which fall within the current week (within remaining days of current week starting from current day).
- birthdays which fall within the current month (within remaining days of current month starting from current day).
- birthdays which fall within the next month.

So all I want to know how to test each date in javascript to see if it falls within the remaining days of the current week/current month/next month.

N.B: say I have those dates in m/d/Y(06/29/1990) format.

Thanks

Comment: [Parse the date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-datetime-string-in-javascript) then use the [accessors](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_date_and_time_functions.cfm) of the Date object and compare the desired fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert your date and current time to [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/) object and use it for comparison. Some dry coding:

```
var now = new Date()
if (
   (check.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear()) &&
   (check.getMonth() == now.getMonth()) &&
   (check.getDate() >= now.getDate())
) {
   // remanining days in current month and today. Use > if you don't need today.
}

var nextMonth = now.getMonth() + 1
var nextYear = now.getFullYear()
if (nextMonth == 12) {
   nextMonth = 0
   nextYear++
}
if (
   (check.getFullYear() == nextYear) &&
   (check.getMonth() == nextMonth)
) {
   // any day in next month. Doesn't include current month remaining days.
}

var now = new Date()
now.setHours(12)
now.setMinutes(0)
now.setSeconds(0)
now.setMilliseconds(0)
var end_of_week = new Date(now.getTime() + (6 - now.getDay()) * 24*60*60*1000 )
end_of_week.setHours(23)
end_of_week.setMinutes(59)
end_of_week.setSeconds(59) // gee, bye-bye leap second
if ( check >=now && check <= end_of_week) {
   // between now and end of week
}
```

Comment: any way to check if the checking date falls within remaining days of current week?

Comment: Yeah. Get current time, add difference between max day of week (6) and current day and use this new end of week time for check.

Comment: I think you need to use this for determining the start date of the week: 
`
var date = new Date();
 var now = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
`

Answer (score 3):

the code Using the Parse Date is

```
var selecteddate = '07/29/1990';
var datestr = selecteddate.split('/');

var month = datestr[0];
var day = datestr[1]; 
var year = datestr[2];

var currentdate = new Date();
var cur_month = currentdate.getMonth() + 1;
var cur_day =currentdate.getDate();
var cur_year =currentdate.getFullYear();

if(cur_month==month && day >= cur_day)
{
 alert("in this month");
}

   else
   {
  alert("not in this month");
   }    ​
```