# How Can I check selected date is in current week or not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I have one problem in JavaScript  that I got many dates from a database and I want to get the date which is in the current week .

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: yes i try many but can't get expected result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392186/how-to-check-a-date-is-within-current-week-or-current-month-or-next-month-in-jav

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: Show us your code? What have you tried? Have a look at MomentJs library

Comment: i try `var curr = new Date;
          var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()));
          var lastday=new Date((curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()))+6);
          ` but  i can not get last day

Comment: Thanks Dear All . i done it .it is very cool. look how i done it.

Comment: `var curr = new Date;
          var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()));
          var totalAppo=response.data.appointment.length;
          
          for(i=0;i<totalAppo;i++)
            {
                var dbdate= new Date(response.data.appointment[i].schedule_date);
                if(dbdate>=firstday)
                {
                    console.log("date get",response.data.appointment[i]);
                }
            }`

Comment: You can give your own answer if it works for your... cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution by doing this

```
    //get first date of current week
var curr = new Date;
var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()));

//cout how much date are in database and use for loop for compare all date
var totalAppo = response.data.appointment.length;
var dbdate = new Date(response.data.appointment[i].schedule_date);

for (i = 0; i < totalAppo; i++) {
  if (dbdate >= firstday) {
    //this date is in current week
  } else {
    //this date in outer of current week
  }
}
```

this way we can get data from database which is in current week

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I googled for you:

[Get week of year in JavaScript like in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php)

Use this function and compare values. But probably it is possible to write more optimal funciton for your purposes.

Comment: It should be a comment not an answer

Comment: true, it's not really an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `mement.js`   method [isBetween](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) to check the date which exists in week or not

```
  if(moment('2010-10-20').isBetween('2010-10-19', '2010-10-25')){
     //return true if exists
    //Do whatever you want
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `moment().week()` from [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

Get the current week like this

```
var c = moment().week();
```

Now to get the week of any date

```
var pastWeek = moment('2016-03-21 20:05:32').week();
```

Compare these two.

P.S : While you explore `moment().week()`, also explore `moment().isoWeek()`