# Javascript - compare date/time now against yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a date/time in an input (#myinput) using the following format:

**yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss**

I need to compare this to todays date, so something like this...

```
var currentdate = new Date(); 
if(currentdate < $("#myinput").val()) {
    alert("HELLO WORLD");
    return false;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-datetime-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I am using moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) for this kind of work.

Would look something like this:

```
var input = moment($("#myinput").val(), "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss");
if(input.diff(moment())>0){
...
```

If i had to use javascript only, i would use a regular expression to parse the date:

```
var dateString = "2012/12/05 12:00:01";

var regexp = /([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})/;
var result = regexp.exec(dateString);

var date = new Date();
date.setYear(result[1]);
date.setMonth(result[2]-1);
date.setDate(result[3]);
date.setHours(result[4]);
date.setMinutes(result[5]);
date.setSeconds(result[6]);

if(new Date()<date){
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date.Parse method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to compare the date inside your input against the current date or other dates in any kind of correct date format.

Ex:

```
    var testDate = $('#myinput').val();

    var d = new Date;

    if (Date.parse(d)<Date.parse(testDate)) {
        }
    else{
        }
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLybp/3/

Comment: That was absolutely not the question

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
//get full data now
function dateNow(){
    var now = new Date(Date.now());
    var dd=now.getDay() + "-" + (now.getMonth()+1) + "-" + now.getFullYear()+"  ";
    dd += now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
    return dd;
}
```

example

```
var d=dateNow();
console.log(d);  // 5-2-2021 1:35:24
```