# Convert string "04/09/2013" MM/DD/YYY to Date Format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert "04/09/2013" to date so I can compare start date and end date like, if (stardate < enddate) { //do this } else {}. I want to convert it to MM/DD/YYYY format.

Comment: Please provide what you've tried and what errors you're running into - if any.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-datetime-string-in-javascript

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) There is a thousand of almost exactly similar questions here. And you didn't even specify whether you want `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: `var d = new Date("04/09/2013");` Watch out for UTC vs. Local time though. This might end up being April 9th or September 4th.

Comment: You may want to read this: http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/03/javascript-and-dates-what-mess.html

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to work with Dates in JavaScript. I highly recommend you use moment.js library

http://momentjs.com/