# Convert string into datetime in razor view with javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

In my controller I convert the datetime into string

here's the code

```
var result = from c in displayedCustomers select new[] { c.NonActiveDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")};
```

and I want to convert it back to datetime cause I want to compare it with today date

this is my code and not working cause the string cannot be compare with date

```
if (d <= Date.now)
{
    return '<span style = "color : red">' + oObj.aData[4]+ '</span>';
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-datetime-string-in-javascript

Comment: Why are you converting it to a string?

Comment: cause i cant get the data into my table if i dont convert it to string in my controller sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your string to Date object in java script using "Date" function before comparing

```
if(new Date("your date string") <= Date.now)
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

cant you fill another string with the date time now and compare them that way.

```
    {
            var time = DateTime.Now;

            string Time = time.ToString();

           if(yourtimevariable == Time)
           {
            //enter what you want to do when the if statement is true
           }
    }
```

Comment: any idea how to fill my string with datetime ?

Comment: with all answer i try,the problem is the same,its not enter the if statement,cause it cant compare the string with Date.Now;