# Converting a date string to a Date Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date-format

My web method is sending a date string to JavaScript e.g. "05/06/2014 09:00:00" in "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" format. But When I try to create a Date object in javascript it inverts the day and month. How Can I have a date object in JavaScript with "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" format.

Comment: Refer <http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp> and <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-datetime-string-in-javascript>

Comment: you can use the [datejs plugin](http://www.datejs.com/) which is verry usefull to do this kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to make the changes.

```
var dateString= ... ; // "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
dateString = dateString.replace( /(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/i , "$2/$1/$3");
// dateString = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"
```