# Converting string to Dateformat in js file

Tags: javascript, date-format

How I can convert string "29-05-2014" to date format in js?
I tried the code given below but it shows an invalid date error message.

```
var date_text = $(".startdate").text(); 
var start_date = new Date(date_text);
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-datetime-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You may try using this:

```
var parseDate = function(txt)
{
    console.log(txt);
    txt = txt.replace(/(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})/, '$2/$1/$3');
    console.log(txt);
    return new Date(txt);
};
alert(parseDate("29-05-2014"));
alert(parseDate("16-06-2014"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use yyyy-mm-dd date format. This works:

```
 a = new Date("2014-05-14");
```