# Extract date part from a string

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to extract only date part from this string if the other text is not fixed:

Input: `"6/27/2014 - is Today"`
Expected: `"6/27/2014"`

Comment: Did you tried it first? if yes than please share your relevant code

Comment: wht I want to do is format the date part to local using IE 11 Intl object and paste it again in that string..

Comment: use regex to get the date

Comment: The answer to your question is, "Yes, there is a way." In fact, there are many ways.  Try one yourself.  Get stuck, then post that code and ask for help. Don't just ask us to code it for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse DateTime string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-datetime-string-in-javascript)

Comment: `str.substr(0, str.indexOf(' '))`

Comment: `str.match(/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/);` is *one of the many ways*.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 That's not Y10k compliant =p

Comment: @Jack - If we are still using JavaScript in the year 10000, then we have a huge problem right here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following snippet:

```
var input = "6/27/2014 - is Today";
var expected = input.match(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/)[0];
console.log(expected);
```

Comment: -[0] worked for me as date comes multiple times

Comment: @Pawan It comes multiple times because the expression contains an unnecessary memory group, i.e. `/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/` would suffice ... still need the `[0]` though :)

Comment: @Jack You're right. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the format all the time then you can also try .split() method

```
var date = "6/27/2014 - is Today".split(" ");
console.log(date[0]);
```